# How can I determine the direction of a jQuery scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for something to this effect:

```
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   if (/* magic code*/ ){
       // upscroll code
   } else {
      // downscroll code
   }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: For those having problems with elastic scrolling, please use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154967/jquery-detect-scrolldown

Comment: Easiest to use the `wheel` event these days : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33334461/3168107.

Answer (score 757, accepted):

Check current `scrollTop` vs previous `scrollTop`

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // downscroll code
   } else {
      // upscroll code
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: Any way to set a sensibility for this ?

Comment: I made an example at [this](http://codepen.io/josiahruddell/pen/piFfq) codepen. Maybe I'll update update this answer with a jQuery plugin because of the popularity.

Comment: Have you tried this if you come back to a previous page having this code ? If you scroll down your page, let say 500PX. Go to another page and then back to initial page. Some browsers keep the scroll position and will bring you back down the page. Will you have a starting `lastScrollTop` at 0 or will it be properly initialised ??

Comment: @TCHdvlp - well worst case scenario the **first** scroll event would update the variable and the **second** event would be accurate (.. it would only matter on an upscroll after back navigation). This could be fixed by setting `var lastScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()` after the browser updates the scroll position on page load.

Comment: On Macs, anyone else notice if you scroll all the way to the bottom that it bounces and will fire off the event?

Comment: You might as well take note of `scrollLeft()` as well. Plenty of scrolling mice and trackpads scroll left and right.

Comment: An update on this: Be careful that some browsers, specially IE 11 on Windows 8, can fire a scroll event subpixel-based (smooth scrolling). But because it reports scrollTop as an integer, your previous scroll value could be the same as the current one.

Comment: @Renato Thanks. I checked same problem at IE 8 on Win 7 and IE 11 on Win 8. In this case, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154967/jquery-detect-scrolldown/#answer-7309786) helped me to solve problem.

Comment: Just a small suggestion on that: Instead of if (st > lastScrollTop) you could also use if (st >= lastScrollTop). Otherwise, I noticed that when I scrolled up, for a moment it was executing the scroll down code before firing up the scroll up code.

Comment: How about detect scroll direction hover non-scrollable content ?

Comment: @cocoacoder did you find anything about the sensibility thing? I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426548/how-to-change-default-scrollspeed-scrollamount-scrollinertia-of-a-webpage#answer-14430585

Comment: When putting function to fire inside "up" or  "down" scroll, it fires a loooot of times.. meaning if you scroll "heavily" on mac (fast pull up with 3 fingers on touchpad), the function will be executed  constantly until scroll actually stops. How come no one mentioned that as its quite important ? Is there a way to detect just scroll start + direction and prevent actual scroll with mouse wheel ?

Comment: @Blue I made and example [here](http://codepen.io/josiahruddell/pen/piFfq), (see the comments above)

Comment: @JosiahRuddell Thank you, but this stil show multiple "down" when scrolled "once". I say "once" as I make usual long scroll down, It should fire only once. For that I managed to make it work with the locker on first scroll and releases locker afted 250ms. In chrome works like a charm, firefox fires two scrolls, on safari it doesnt really work..well, sensitivity is high so if scrolling gently wanted effect is achieved. This is how the scroll should work [here](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).Plugin for WP is pretty shitty and awful to build page so I had to made it myself..

Comment: Im talking about mouse wheel scroll just to clarify :)

Comment: this what i thought up on my own, but this approach creates so many potential issues!!

Comment: @cocoacoder try this:
var lastScrTop = 0;
    var lastScrolltrig = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st > lastScrTop){
            // downscroll code
            lastScrolltrig = 0;
        }
        else {
            // upscroll code
            if ( lastScrolltrig === 0 ) {
                lastScrolltrig = $(this).scrollTop();
            }
            if ( lastScrolltrig - $(this).scrollTop() >= 300 ) {
                // 300px buffer, run code here
            }
        }
        lastScrTop = st;
    });

Answer (score 181):

You can do it without having to keep track of the previous scroll top, as all the other examples require:

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
        console.log('Scroll up');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Scroll down');
    }
});
```

I am not an expert on this so feel free to research it further, but it appears that when you use `$(element).scroll`, the event being listened for is a 'scroll' event.

But if you specifically listen for a `mousewheel` event by using bind, the `originalEvent` attribute of the event parameter to your callback contains different information.  Part of that information is `wheelDelta`.  If it's positive, you moved the mousewheel up.  If it's negative, you moved the mousewheel down.

My guess is that `mousewheel` events will fire when the mouse wheel turns, even if the page does not scroll; a case in which 'scroll' events probably are not fired.  If you want, you can call `event.preventDefault()` at the bottom of your callback to prevent the page from scrolling, and so that you can use the mousewheel event for something other than a page scroll, like some type of zoom functionality.

Comment: Nice but sadly the one and only Firefox is not supporting it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mousewheel (tested in FF v15). :C

Comment: This was useful for me: I needed to detect scrolling, even though the page itself didn't actually scroll, so `scrollTop` didn't update. In fact, `$(window).scroll()` didn't fire at all.

Comment: It's nice that you don't need the old state.  However this technique will not work on mobiles or tablets, since they don't have a mousewheel!

Comment: I found this to be a nice and easy solution in firefox and chrome. Thank you good sir

Comment: This approach won't work if I scroll with the keyboard. It's definitely an interesting approach for things like zoom, but I don't think it addresses the scroll direction question.

Comment: while I used this technique until now, it won't work if the page is scrolled without the mousewheel. e.g. via mouse on the scrollbar. Also: Firefox only supports `DOMmousescroll`

Comment: $("html, body").bind({'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll onmousewheel touchmove scroll': function(e) { //... }); works for me in detecting all browser scroll data

Comment: Can the console.log wait until the scroll happens twice?

Comment: that's just plain bad. Touch scroll? scroll by clicking on the scrollbar and moving it down? just nope

Comment: +1 because this led me in the right direction to solve my problem: `event.wheelDeltaX` and `event.wheelDeltaY`

Comment: Note that mousewheel and scroll are not the same events. This will only work if user scrolls with mousewheel or touchpad.

Comment: Dude you saved my day with your mousewheel event. For some reason I couldn't get scroll event fired up at all, but your solution worked like a charm!!! Thanx!

Comment: Good idea, but Firefox (75) doesn't like it at all. Even when doing it like @GoreDefex described.

Answer (score 34):

### Existing Solution

There could be **3 solution** from this posting and [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154967/jquery-detect-scrolldown/#answer-7309786).

**Solution 1**

```
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(st < lastScrollTop) {
            console.log('up 1');
        }
        else {
            console.log('down 1');
        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
    });
```

**Solution 2**

```
    $('body').on('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
            console.log('up 2');
        }
        else {
            console.log('down 2');
        }
    });
```

**Solution 3**

```
    $('body').on('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
            console.log('up 3');
        }
        else {
            console.log('down 3');
        }
    });
```

---

### Multi Browser Test

*I couldn't tested it on Safari*

chrome 42 (Win 7)

- Solution 1

  - Up : 1 event per 1 scroll
  - Down : 1 event per 1 scroll
- Solution 2

  - Up : Not working
  - Down : Not working
- Solution 3

  - Up : 1 event per 1 scroll
  - Down : 1 event per 1 scroll

Firefox 37 (Win 7)

- Solution 1

  - Up : 20 events per 1 scroll
  - Down : 20 events per 1 scroll
- Solution 2

  - Up : Not working
  - Down : 1 event per 1 scroll
- Solution 3

  - Up : Not working
  - Down : Not working

IE 11 (Win 8)

- Solution 1

  - Up : 10 events per 1 scroll (side effect : down scroll occured at last)
  - Down : 10 events per 1 scroll
- Solution 2

  - Up : Not working
  - Down : Not working
- Solution 3

  - Up : Not working
  - Down : 1 event per 1 scroll

IE 10 (Win 7)

- Solution 1

  - Up : 1 event per 1 scroll
  - Down : 1 event per 1 scroll
- Solution 2

  - Up : Not working
  - Down : Not working
- Solution 3

  - Up : 1 event per 1 scroll
  - Down : 1 event per 1 scroll

IE 9 (Win 7)

- Solution 1

  - Up : 1 event per 1 scroll
  - Down : 1 event per 1 scroll
- Solution 2

  - Up : Not working
  - Down : Not working
- Solution 3

  - Up : 1 event per 1 scroll
  - Down : 1 event per 1 scroll

IE 8 (Win 7)

- Solution 1

  - Up : 2 events per 1 scroll (side effect : down scroll occured at last)
  - Down : 2~4 events per 1 scroll
- Solution 2

  - Up : Not working
  - Down : Not working
- Solution 3

  - Up : 1 event per 1 scroll
  - Down : 1 event per 1 scroll

---

### Combined Solution

> I checked that side effect from IE 11 and IE 8 is come from `if else` statement. So, I replaced it with `if else if` statement as following.

From the multi browser test, I decided to use **Solution 3** for common browsers and **Solution 1** for firefox and IE 11.

I referred [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907445/how-to-detect-ie11/#answer-20815285) to detect IE 11.

```
    // Detect IE version
    var iev=0;
    var ieold = (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent));
    var trident = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7.0/);
    var rv=navigator.userAgent.indexOf("rv:11.0");

    if (ieold) iev=new Number(RegExp.$1);
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 10") != -1) iev=10;
    if (trident&&rv!=-1) iev=11;

    // Firefox or IE 11
    if(typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined' || iev == 11) {
        var lastScrollTop = 0;
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
            st = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(st < lastScrollTop) {
                console.log('Up');
            }
            else if(st > lastScrollTop) {
                console.log('Down');
            }
            lastScrollTop = st;
        });
    }
    // Other browsers
    else {
        $('body').on('mousewheel', function(e){
            if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
                console.log('Up');
            }
            else if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
                console.log('Down');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: If someone could add result of `Safari browser`, it would be helpful to supplement solution.

Comment: Oops! I found that Mobile Chrome and Android default browser are only covered by Solution 1. So it would be better to use both Solution 1 and 3 together to cover various browsers.

Comment: Will not work if the design is a fixed layout design. If you want to detect the scroll direction on a static no-scroll website, Firefox and IE11 will not work

Comment: I find that when I use this it uses the "Other Browsers" in chrome, this is not really much use when you wish to detect scrolling by both mouse wheel and scroll bar. 

.scroll will detect both types of scrolling in chrome.

Answer (score 33):

Store the previous scroll location, then see if the new one is greater than or less than that.

Here's a way to avoid any global variables ([fiddle available here](http://jsfiddle.net/VyU97/1/)):

```
(function () {
    var previousScroll = 0;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
       var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (currentScroll > previousScroll){
           alert('down');
       } else {
          alert('up');
       }
       previousScroll = currentScroll;
    });
}()); //run this anonymous function immediately
```

Answer (score 12):

I understand there has already been an accepted answer, but wanted to post what I am using in case it can help anyone. I get the direction like `cliphex` with the mousewheel event but with support for Firefox. It's useful doing it this way in case you are doing something like locking scroll and can't get the current scroll top.

See a live version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u9xdnyfL/1/).

```
$(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {

    var direction = (function () {

        var delta = (e.type === 'DOMMouseScroll' ?
                     e.originalEvent.detail * -40 :
                     e.originalEvent.wheelDelta);

        return delta > 0 ? 0 : 1;
    }());

    if(direction === 1) {
       // scroll down
    }
    if(direction === 0) {
       // scroll up
    }
});
```

Comment: @EtienneMartin the above code relies on jQuery if that's what was causing your error. Please see the attached fiddle to see it working.

Answer (score 8):

## Scroll Event

The **[scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll)** behaves oddly in FF (it is fired a lot of times because of the smoothness scrolling) but it works.

***Note:** The [scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event actually **is fired** when dragging the scroll bar, using cursor keys or mousewheel.*

```
//creates an element to print the scroll position
$("<p id='test'>").appendTo("body").css({
    padding: "5px 7px",
    background: "#e9e9e9",
    position: "fixed",
    bottom: "15px",
    left: "35px"
});

//binds the "scroll" event
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    var target = e.currentTarget,
        self = $(target),
        scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || target.scrollTop,
        lastScrollTop = self.data("lastScrollTop") || 0,
        scrollHeight = target.scrollHeight || document.body.scrollHeight,
        scrollText = "";

    if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
        scrollText = "<b>scroll down</b>";
    } else {
        scrollText = "<b>scroll up</b>";
    }

    $("#test").html(scrollText +
      "<br>innerHeight: " + self.innerHeight() +
      "<br>scrollHeight: " + scrollHeight +
      "<br>scrollTop: " + scrollTop +
      "<br>lastScrollTop: " + lastScrollTop);

    if (scrollHeight - scrollTop === self.innerHeight()) {
      console.log("► End of scroll");
    }

    //saves the current scrollTop
    self.data("lastScrollTop", scrollTop);
});
```

---

## Wheel Event

You also may take a look at MDN, it exposes a great information about the **[Wheel Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel).**

***Note:** The wheel event **is fired only when using the mousewheel**; cursor keys and dragging the scroll bar does not fire the event.*

I read the document and the example: ***[Listening to this event across browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel#Listening_to_this_event_across_browser)***
and after some tests with FF, IE, chrome, safari, I ended up with this snippet:

```
//creates an element to print the scroll position
$("<p id='test'>").appendTo("body").css({
    padding: "5px 7px",
    background: "#e9e9e9",
    position: "fixed",
    bottom: "15px",
    left: "15px"
});

//attach the "wheel" event if it is supported, otherwise "mousewheel" event is used
$("html").on(("onwheel" in document.createElement("div") ? "wheel" : "mousewheel"), function (e) {
    var evt = e.originalEvent || e;

    //this is what really matters
    var deltaY = evt.deltaY || (-1 / 40 * evt.wheelDelta), //wheel || mousewheel
        scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop() || $("body").scrollTop(), //fix safari
        scrollText = "";

    if (deltaY > 0) {
        scrollText = "<b>scroll down</b>";
    } else {
        scrollText = "<b>scroll up</b>";
    }

    //console.log("Event: ", evt);
    $("#test").html(scrollText +
      "<br>clientHeight: " + this.clientHeight +
      "<br>scrollHeight: " + this.scrollHeight +
      "<br>scrollTop: " + scrollTop +
      "<br>deltaY: " + deltaY);
});
```

Comment: I have a fixed panel view which disables the actual scroll bar, so I needed to detect the direction from the mouse wheel. Your mousewheel solution worked perfectly cross browser so thankyou for that!

Answer (score 8):

In case you just want to know if you scroll up or down using a pointer device (mouse or track pad) you can use the [deltaY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaY) property of the `wheel` event.

```js
$('.container').on('wheel', function(event) {
  if (event.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) {
    $('.result').append('Scrolled down!<br>');
  } else {
    $('.result').append('Scrolled up!<br>');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.content {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Scroll me!
  </div>
</div>

<div class="result">
  <p>Action:</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This link says not to rely on deltaY https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel

Answer (score 4):

### Update 2021-04-07

[Bobort](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603819/bobort) in a comment (thanks!) pointed to the new note added in the [wheel documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel):

> Don't confuse the wheel event with the scroll event. The default action of a wheel event is implementation-specific, and doesn't necessarily dispatch a scroll event. Even when it does, the **delta* values in the wheel event don't necessarily reflect the content's scrolling direction**. Therefore, do not rely on the wheel event's delta* properties to get the scrolling direction. Instead, detect value changes of scrollLeft and scrollTop of the target in the scroll event.

However, the example given in the documentation uses delta to scale, which implies a scroll up for zooming out and scroll down for zooming in.

The code below worked for me in different browsers to detect direction, but given that note, use it at your own risk.

### Original answer

Since [`bind` has been deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) on v3 ("superseded by [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)") and [`wheel` is now supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel), forget `wheelDelta`:

```js
$(window).on('wheel', function(e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) {
    console.log('down');
  } else if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
    console.log('up');
  } else if (e.originalEvent.deltaX > 0) {
    console.log('right');
  } else if (e.originalEvent.deltaX < 0) {
    console.log('left');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:scroll">
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
</h1>
```

`wheel` event's [Browser Compatibility on MDN's (2019-03-18)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel#Browser_compatibility):

[image: Compatibility of the wheel event]

Comment: Code above produces two console logs, use the following to fully separate out up/down/left/right:  

```if(e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) {
        console.log('down');
    } else if(e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
        console.log('up');
    } else if(e.originalEvent.deltaX > 0) {
        console.log('right');
    } else if(e.originalEvent.deltaX < 0) {
        console.log('left');
    }
```

Comment: For mobile use [`touchmove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchmove_event) event instead.

Comment: I checked the documentation, and when detecting the direction of a scroll, it explicitly states the following: "do not rely on the wheel event's `delta*` properties to get the scrolling direction. Instead, detect value changes of `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` of the target in the scroll event."

Comment: Appreciated @Bobort, I adjusted my answer based on that note.

Comment: @DonWilson thank you! Just updated the answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

```
var tempScrollTop, currentScrollTop = 0; 

$(window).scroll(function(){ 

   currentScrollTop = $("#div").scrollTop(); 

   if (tempScrollTop > currentScrollTop ) {
       // upscroll code
   }
  else if (tempScrollTop < currentScrollTop ){
      // downscroll code
  }

  tempScrollTop = currentScrollTop; 
}
```

or use the [mousewheel extension](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/mousewheel), see [here](http://upandcrawling.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/cool-jquery-stuff-for-beginners-part-1/).

Answer (score 3):

I have seen many version of good answers here but it seems some folks are having cross browser issues so this is my fix.

I have used this successfully to detect direction in FF, IE and Chrome ... I haven't tested it in safari  as I use windows typically.

```
$("html, body").bind({'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll onmousewheel touchmove scroll': 
    function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'el') return;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        //Determine Direction
        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta && e.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
            //Up
            alert("up");

        } else if (e.originalEvent.detail && e.originalEvent.detail <= 0) {
            //Up
            alert("up");

        } else {
            //Down
            alert("down");
        }
    }
});
```

Keep in mind I also use this to stop any scrolling so if you want scrolling to still occur you must remove the `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: always returns down on android GS5

Comment: This worked great! I had an issue with the top voted answer on IE. This does not have that issue! +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

To ignore any snap / momentum / bounce back at the top and bottom of the page, here is a modified version of [Josiah's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4326907/836247):

```
var prevScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){

    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if ( scrollTop < 0 ) {
        scrollTop = 0;
    }
    if ( scrollTop > $('body').height() - $(window).height() ) {
        scrollTop = $('body').height() - $(window).height();
    }

    if (scrollTop >= prevScrollTop && scrollTop) {
        // scrolling down
    } else {
        // scrolling up
    }

    prevScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can determin mousewhell direction.

```
$(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
    var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta ? 
                   e.originalEvent.wheelDelta : -e.originalEvent.detail;

    if (delta >= 0) {
        console.log('scroll up');
    } else {
        console.log('scroll down');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this to find the scroll direction. This is only to find the direction of the Vertical Scroll. Supports all cross browsers.

```
    var scrollableElement = document.getElementById('scrollableElement');

    scrollableElement.addEventListener('wheel', findScrollDirectionOtherBrowsers);

    function findScrollDirectionOtherBrowsers(event){
        var delta;

        if (event.wheelDelta){
            delta = event.wheelDelta;
        }else{
            delta = -1 * event.deltaY;
        }

        if (delta < 0){
            console.log("DOWN");
        }else if (delta > 0){
            console.log("UP");
        }

    }
```

[Example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FGMBL0BDC4TA)

Answer (score 3):

this code work fine with IE, Firefox, Opera and Chrome:

```
$(window).bind('wheel mousewheel', function(event) {
      if (event.originalEvent.deltaY >= 0) {
          console.log('Scroll down');
      }
      else {
          console.log('Scroll up');
      }
  });
```

**'wheel mousewheel'** and the property **deltaY** must be use in **bind()** function.

Remember : You're user must update their system and browsers for security reasons. In 2018, the excuses of "I have IE 7" is a nonsense. We must educate users.

Have a good day :)

Comment: I tried your code and it's the other way. First one is triggered when scrolling down and second one when scrolling up.

Comment: Hi :) Thanks AlexioVay. I edited my code (About time too!) ^^. Of course "console.log('.......')" it's just an exemple of what we can do.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it super simple:

**jQuery Event Listener Way:**

```
$(window).on('wheel', function(){
  whichDirection(event);
});
```

**Vanilla JavaScript Event Listener Way:**

```
if(window.addEventListener){
  addEventListener('wheel', whichDirection, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  attachEvent('wheel', whichDirection, false);
}
```

**Function Remains The Same:**

```
function whichDirection(event){
  console.log(event + ' WheelEvent has all kinds of good stuff to work with');
  var scrollDirection = event.deltaY;
  if(scrollDirection === 1){
    console.log('meet me at the club, going down', scrollDirection);
  } else if(scrollDirection === -1) {
    console.log('Going up, on a tuesday', scrollDirection);
  }
}
```

I wrote a more indepth post on it [here](https://tmblr.co/Z_o-Hx2EPkxdJ)
​​​​​​​

Comment: Is jquery-wheel required to use the jquery version?

Comment: jquery-wheel is not required for this @HastigZusammenstellen

Answer (score 2):

You can use both scroll and mousewheel option to track up and down movement at once.

```
 $('body').bind('scroll mousewheel', function(event) {

if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
      console.log('moving down');   
    }
    else {
      console.log('moving up'); 
    }
});
```

You can replace 'body' with (window) as well.

Comment: Seems to work fine in Chrome but not in FF (55.0.2, Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

stock an increment in the `.data ()` of element scrolled, you will then be able to test number of times the scroll reached top.

Answer (score 1):

Why nobody use the `event` object returned by `jQuery` on scroll ?

```
$window.on('scroll', function (event) {
    console.group('Scroll');
    console.info('Scroll event:', event);
    console.info('Position:', this.pageYOffset);
    console.info('Direction:', event.originalEvent.dir); // Here is the direction
    console.groupEnd();
});
```

I'm using `chromium` and I didn't checked on other browsers if they have the `dir` property.

Comment: No "dir" attribute in Chrome 86.0.4240.111

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as well

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var currentscroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
Get_page_scroll_direction();
});

function Get_page_scroll_direction(){
  var running_scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(running_scroll_position > currentscroll_position) {
      
      $('.direction_value').text('Scrolling Down Scripts');

  } else {
       
       $('.direction_value').text('Scrolling Up Scripts');

  }
  currentscroll_position = running_scroll_position;
}

});
```

```css
.direction_value{
  position: fixed;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="direction_value">
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ducimus expedita facilis architecto fugiat veniam natus suscipit amet beatae atque, enim recusandae quos, magnam, perferendis accusamus cumque nemo modi unde!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ducimus expedita facilis architecto fugiat veniam natus suscipit amet beatae atque, enim recusandae quos, magnam, perferendis accusamus cumque nemo modi unde!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ducimus expedita facilis architecto fugiat veniam natus suscipit amet beatae atque, enim recusandae quos, magnam, perferendis accusamus cumque nemo modi unde!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ducimus expedita facilis architecto fugiat veniam natus suscipit amet beatae atque, enim recusandae quos, magnam, perferendis accusamus cumque nemo modi unde!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ducimus expedita facilis architecto fugiat veniam natus suscipit amet beatae atque, enim recusandae quos, magnam, perferendis accusamus cumque nemo modi unde!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ducimus expedita facilis architecto fugiat veniam natus suscipit amet beatae atque, enim recusandae quos, magnam, perferendis accusamus cumque nemo modi unde!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the `.data()` of the element you can store a JSON and test values to launch events

```
{ top : 1,
   first_top_event: function(){ ...},
   second_top_event: function(){ ...},
   third_top_event: function(){ ...},
   scroll_down_event1: function(){ ...},
   scroll_down_event2: function(){ ...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and easy detection for when the user scrolls away from the top of the page and for when they return to the top.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        // User has scrolled
    } else {
        // User at top of page
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an optimal solution for detecting the direction just when the user end scrolling.

```
var currentScrollTop = 0 ;

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {     

    scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {

        if(scrollTop > currentScrollTop){
            // downscroll code
            $('.mfb-component--bl').addClass('mfbHide');
        }else{
            // upscroll code
            $('.mfb-component--bl').removeClass('mfbHide');
        }
        currentScrollTop = scrollTop;

    }, 250));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should try this

```
var scrl
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() < scrl){
            //some code while previous scroll
        }else{
            if($(window).scrollTop() > 200){
                //scroll while downward
            }else{//scroll while downward after some specific height
            }
        }
        scrl = $(window).scrollTop();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had **problems** with **elastic scrolling** (scroll bouncing, rubber-banding).
Ignoring the down-scroll event if close to the page top worked for me.

```
var position = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var downScroll = scroll > position;
    var closeToTop = -120 < scroll && scroll < 120;
    if (downScroll && !closeToTop) {
        // scrolled down and not to close to top (to avoid Ipad elastic scroll-problems)
        $('.top-container').slideUp('fast');
        $('.main-header').addClass('padding-top');
    } else {
        // scrolled up
        $('.top-container').slideDown('fast');
        $('.main-header').removeClass('padding-top');
    }
    position = scroll;
});
```

Comment: What does the 120 mean? Perhaps use a const to better explain what the 120 is.

Answer (score 0):

This works in all pc or phones browsers, expanding on the top answers. One can build a more complex event object window["scroll_evt"] then call it in the handleScroll() function. This one triggers for 2 concurrent conditions, if certain delay has elapsed or certain delta is passed to eliminate some unwanted triggers.

```
window["scroll_evt"]={"delta":0,"delay":0,"direction":0,"time":Date.now(),"pos":$(window).scrollTop(),"min_delta":120,"min_delay":10};
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    var currentTime = Date.now();
    var boolRun=(window["scroll_evt"]["min_delay"]>0)?(Math.abs(currentTime - window["scroll_evt"]["time"])>window["scroll_evt"]["min_delay"]):false;
    boolRun = boolRun && ((window["scroll_evt"]["min_delta"]>0)?(Math.abs(currentScroll - window["scroll_evt"]["pos"])>window["scroll_evt"]["min_delta"]):false);
    if(boolRun){
        window["scroll_evt"]["delta"] = currentScroll - window["scroll_evt"]["pos"];
        window["scroll_evt"]["direction"] = window["scroll_evt"]["delta"]>0?'down':'up';
        window["scroll_evt"]["delay"] =currentTime - window["scroll_evt"]["time"];//in milisecs!!!
        window["scroll_evt"]["pos"] = currentScroll;
        window["scroll_evt"]["time"] = currentTime;
        handleScroll();
    }
});


function handleScroll(){
    event.stopPropagation();
    //alert(window["scroll_evt"]["direction"]);
    console.log(window["scroll_evt"]);
}
```