# Detect user scroll down or scroll up in jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, scroll, bind

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Differentiate between scroll up/down in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989632/differentiate-between-scroll-up-down-in-jquery)

Is it possible to detect if user scroll down or scroll up ?

Example :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    // IF USER SCROLL DOWN 
           DO ACTION

    // IF USER SCROLL UP 
           DO ANOTHER ACTION

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 48):

To differentiate between scroll up/down in jQuery, you could use:

```
var mousewheelevt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" //FF doesn't recognize mousewheel as of FF3.x
$('#yourDiv').bind(mousewheelevt, function(e){

    var evt = window.event || e //equalize event object     
    evt = evt.originalEvent ? evt.originalEvent : evt; //convert to originalEvent if possible               
    var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail*(-40) : evt.wheelDelta //check for detail first, because it is used by Opera and FF

    if(delta > 0) {
        //scroll up
    }
    else{
        //scroll down
    }   
});
```

This method also works in divs that have `overflow:hidden`.

I successfully tested it in FireFox, IE and Chrome.

Comment: This works very well! A simple ```e.preventDefault()``` will also not allow your scroll to go to any parent elements (like the page) if you're just wanting to do something on the scroll of a section and not actually scroll your element or its parents

Comment: any ideas for this on apple trackpad or magic mouse with overflow hidden? http://stackoverflow.com/q/32512924/770127

Comment: This shouldn't be done anymore, browser sniffing hasn't been great practice for quite a while. There's another cross browser event now that'll be better to use. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33334461/3168107

Comment: This works really nice however doesn't work when I click my mouse wheel to scroll.

Comment: Thank you for the working snippet @Jordi van Duijn

Comment: change .bind to .on, .bind() is deprecated