# jQuery: What function to use to scroll one div from any point in window

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, scroll

I'm working on a website where I want a div with text in it to scroll down/up whenever I scroll down/up from any point of the window. The website is made in such a way that the user never has to scroll the page down. All information can be found in that div so I want that to go down/up when they want to read more.

I have been using jQuery on regular bases. I know the syntax but I'm not an advanced user.

So the objective that I want to achieve: From any point of the window text in a div has to go down/up.

I'm not giving you an assignment, I just need your help. All I want to know is what jQuery or just procedural JavaScript function I should use.

Here are the suggestions I found: scroll(); scrollBy(); scrollDown(); scrollUp(); etc etc. What should I use?

Thanks in advance!

John

Comment: Anyhow in order to implement this you will need to "catch" the scrolling event when one takes place. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957860/detect-user-scroll-down-or-scroll-up-in-jquery

Comment: css `position:fixed` ?