# Detect user scroll attempt when overflow is hidden

Tags: javascript, scroll, mouseevent, dom-events, mouse

`"scroll"` does not fire when content is `overflow: hidden`. `"wheel"` fires for wheel mouses but not on a [magic trackpad](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC380LL/A/magic-trackpad) or [magic mouse](http://www.apple.com/magicmouse/). How can I detect the mouse interaction of attempting to scroll in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the mouse coordinates and other [properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) like `movement` easily.

Using that position you can choose when trigger an wheel event or just make the script to scroll the page.

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seler/pAu8Q/) (not mine) to get inspired