# how to hide navigation menu bar on scroll down and it should appear on scrolling up using angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

How to hide `navigation menu bar` on `scroll down` and it should appear on `scrolling up` using `angularjs`?
As I have seen a solution that library 'headroom.js' is quite useful but I am unable to implement.Please suggest an appropriate solution.

Comment: Can I have solution using ng-hide or ng-show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can it be done with JQuery? I am using code like this in my app, you can use it in AngularJS if you use `angular.element(document).ready`.

```
// Navigation Scripts to Show Header on Scroll-Up
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var MQL = 1170;

//primary navigation slide-in effect
  if ($(window).width() > MQL) {
    var headerHeight = $('.navbar-custom').height();
    $(window).on('scroll', {
      previousTop: 0
    },
    function() {
      var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      //check if user is scrolling up
      if (currentTop < this.previousTop) {
        //if scrolling up...
        if (currentTop > 0 && $('.navbar-custom').hasClass('is-fixed')) {
          $('.navbar-custom').addClass('is-visible');
        } else {
          $('.navbar-custom').removeClass('is-visible is-fixed');
        }
      } else if (currentTop > this.previousTop) {
        //if scrolling down...
        $('.navbar-custom').removeClass('is-visible');
        if (currentTop > headerHeight && !$('.navbar-custom').hasClass('is-fixed')) $('.navbar-custom').addClass('is-fixed');
      }
      this.previousTop = currentTop;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually, I did it using `jquery`. But requirement is different. i need a solution in pure angularjs. @tommybernaciak

Comment: if it possible to you to give a solution in with the `making` use of angularjs directives. Then provide me.

Comment: hey! @tommybernaciak. I need a help from your side. please a look to this issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348123/how-to-prevent-showing-login-page-after-user-logged-and-hit-browser-back-button

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this post: [scroll up/down detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957860/detect-user-scroll-down-or-scroll-up-in-jquery)

You can use this:

```
var mousewheelevt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" //FF doesn't recognize mousewheel as of FF3.x
$('body').bind(mousewheelevt, function(e){

var evt = window.event || e //equalize event object     
evt = evt.originalEvent ? evt.originalEvent : evt; //convert to originalEvent if possible               
var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail*(-40) : evt.wheelDelta //check for detail first, because it is used by Opera and FF

  if(delta > 0) {
    $('.menu').fadeIn();
  }
  else{
    $('.menu').fadeOut();
  }   
});
```

Comment: it is useful but i am looking for a solution in angularjs.

Comment: Sorry my friend, I do not know angular.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example solution you can check out [here](https://kolosek.com/navigation-on-scroll/). It is solved using CSS and JQuery.