# Is there a javascript event listener that detects only when the user scrolls up, or only when the user scrolls down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I know .scroll() detects scrolling but what if I want something to happen only when the user scrolls down or vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a listener for this, but you can have a variable with last position scrolled and check against new one. So it would be something like this:

Keep a variable, say, `last_scroll_position`, and when you have a scroll, if `last_scroll_position - current_position > 0`, the user scrolled up, and down if it's less than 0.

For further reference:

[Differentiate between scroll up/down in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989632/differentiate-between-scroll-up-down-in-jquery)

Example:

```
<div style='height:10000px;'>

var last_scroll=0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var direction='none';
    var current_scroll=$(this).scrollTop();
    if(current_scroll < last_scroll) direction='up';
    else if(current_scroll > last_scroll) direction = 'down';
    last_scroll=current_scroll;
    console.log(direction)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. The logic behind this seems simple enough, the only problem I am having is capturing the value for <code>last_scroll_position</code>. I have a function that captures <code>scrollTop</code> so creating the variable for the current scroll position is pretty easy. Just can't wrap my head around how to capture the previous scroll position.

Comment: @tripstar added a code example, hope it helps!