# Detect swipe direction without scrolling

Tags: javascript, mobile, scroll

How can I detect the swipe direction without actually scrolling?  Here's what I'm doing:

```js
function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault;

window.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
  if (e.deltaY < 0) {
    console.log('scrolling up');
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'scrolling up';
  }
  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    console.log('scrolling down');
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'scrolling down';
  }
});
```

```html
<div style='height: 2000px; border: 5px solid gray; touch-action: none;'>
 <p id='status'></p>
</div>
```

What I observe is that although the screen does not scroll, none of the event listener code executes.  This is because there is no 'deltaY' property in the event.  I used the [equivalent code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34147719/2233706) on desktop with the 'wheel' event to detect the scroll direction without scrolling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
let start = null;

window.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    start = e.changedTouches[0];
});


window.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
  let end = e.changedTouches[0];

  if(end.screenY - start.screenY > 0)
  {
      console.log('scrolling up');
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'scrolling up';
  }
  else if(end.screenY - start.screenY < 0)
  {
      console.log('scrolling down');
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'scrolling down';
  }
});
```