# wheel Event Reliability

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a web project that has animations and page changes on the scroll ( specifically, scroll **direction** ) and I've been looking for multiple possible **good** and reliable solutions.

I've been detecting the scroll direction by detected the window's `scrollY` with the user's previously saved `scrollY` that I have saved in a variable. The only problem is that the `scroll` event doesn't fire when at the top or the bottom of page, even though the content is all absolute/fixed positioned.

I want to turn to the `wheel` event because of its `deltaY` values from the event, and it still fires when at the top of bottom of the page so I can remove the scrollbar and keep the body of the page `100vh`.

The **Mozilla** dev docs say:

> Don't confuse the wheel event with the scroll event. The default
>   action of a wheel event is implementation-specific, and doesn't
>   necessarily dispatch a scroll event. Even when it does, the `delta*`
>   values in the wheel event don't necessarily reflect the content's
>   scrolling direction. Therefore, do not rely on the wheel event's
>   `delta*` properties to get the scrolling direction. Instead, detect
>   value changes of `scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` of the target in the `scroll`
>   event.
>   (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event)

And I'm also curious if the `wheel` event will work correctly on mobile with *touch*?

Here's a good example of what I'm trying to replicate: https://reed.be 
There is no scrollbar, yet things still happen based on your scrolling.

**CanIuse** shows full compatibility of the `wheel` event with modern browsers, and some older versions.

see here -> https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_wheelevent

I've found a solution that references the `wheel` event ([How to determine scroll direction without actually scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217087/how-to-determine-scroll-direction-without-actually-scrolling)), though my question still applies -

**How reliable is the `wheel` event across devices and browsers, including mobile?**

I am limited to my own current version browsers and android devices for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can fool the browser by setting the additional height on the body to match the content width and setting the overflow to scroll. Then use some basic script, to set the `scrollLeft` property of your container to equal the window `scrollY`.

You will need to set the height of the body equal to the total width of the panels.

```
body {
   height: 400vh; // 4 panels of 100vw each
   ...
}

.panel {
   width: 100vw;
   ...
}
```

**JS**

```
const viewPort = document.querySelector('#viewport');

let lastScroll = 0;
window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
  let scrollY = window.scrollY;

  // scroll the container by and equal amount of your window scroll
  viewPort.scrollLeft = scrollY;

  lastScroll = scrollY;
});
```

[Rough JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f1ur4739/134/)

Comment: Hey man thanks for providing your way of doing this type of deal. However, I'm not going to mark it as a solution since it's kind of 'hacky'. Don't get me wrong though, still a great solution.

Comment: @Zac like the demo said - it's a `Rough JSFiddle Demo`, done quickly to show you concepts to tackle the issue of "The only problem is that the scroll event doesn't fire when at the top or the bottom of page, even though the content is all absolute/fixed positioned." and how to allow the page to continue scrolling. Feel free to use or lose.