# Scroll in visible on Page using React

Tags: reactjs, dom

I want to check weather vertical scroll is appear on page using React, and also want dom height and browser height using react.

Answer (score 0):

You can call plain vanilla window object in the component by window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth to get the height and width.

Answer (score 0):

you can find 2 usefull answers in here:
[Detecting scroll direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223341/detecting-scroll-direction)
and here: 
[How to determine scroll direction without actually scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217087/how-to-determine-scroll-direction-without-actually-scrolling/34147719)

about scrolling...
and for the height: window.innerHeight() -  window.outerHeight()