# Show div on scroll down effect in a page that occupies full height

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, touchpad

I have the following structure:

```
<body>
    <div id="first-div">
      <div id="second-div"></div>
      <div id="third-div"></div>
    </div>
</body>

#first-div {
      height: 100%;
}
#second-div, #third-div {
  display: none;
}
```

Upon detecting the first scroll down event I need the #second-div to be displayed, If a second scroll down event is detected, I need #third-div to be displayed and #second-div to be hidden. My problem is: a single scroll down on the touchpad might trigger multiple events thus showing the #second-div and #third-div immediately.

```
$(body).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (event) {
                                if (event.originalEvent.detail > 0 || event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
                                    //scroll down
                                    console.log('Down');
                                } else {
                                    //scroll up
                                    console.log('Up');
                                }
                                //prevent page fom scrolling
                                return false;
                            });
```

How Can I detect the scroll down event, stop the scroll event and show #second-div. Then detect another scroll down event, stop the scroll event and hide #second-div and show #third-div?

Also, Afterwards, I detect the scroll up event, stop the scroll event and hide #third-div and show #second-div. Then detect another scroll up event, stop the scroll event and hide #second-div?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) library?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet uses the [scroll](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) method of JQuery
(there's a similar question: [Differentiate between scroll up/down in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989632/differentiate-between-scroll-up-down-in-jquery))

```js
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  var target = e.currentTarget,
    $self = $(target),
    scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || target.scrollTop,
    lastScrollTop = $self.data("lastScrollTop") || 0,
    scrollHeight = target.scrollHeight || document.body.scrollHeight,
    scrollText = "";

  if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
    scrollText = "<b>scroll down</b>";
  } else {
    scrollText = "<b>scroll up</b>";
  }

  $(".test").html(scrollText +
    "<br>innerHeight: " + $self.innerHeight() +
    "<br>scrollHeight: " + scrollHeight +
    "<br>scrollTop: " + scrollTop +
    "<br>lastScrollTop: " + lastScrollTop +
    "<br>" + scrollText);

  if (scrollHeight - scrollTop === $self.innerHeight()) {
    console.log("► End of " + scrollText);
  }

  //saves the current scrollTop
  $self.data("lastScrollTop", scrollTop);
});
```

```css
#first-div {
  height: 100%;
}
#second-div,
#third-div {
  display: none;
}
.test {
  margin: 200px auto 200px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first-div">
  <div class="test">
    scroll info</div>
</div>
<div id="second-div">
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
<div id="third-div">
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I don't understand how can I use this to solve my problem. A single touch pad scroll down event will make this code run multiple times if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
    scrollText = "<b>scroll down</b>";
  } else {
    scrollText = "<b>scroll up</b>";
  } .... thus showing my second and third div simultaneously... when a scroll down event occur, I want to first shown #second-div and when a new scroll event is generated show third-div.... with the current code I don't seem to able to understand how to limit the scroll down to showing one div instead of two...

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to use [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) to save time and **have a much better result**. 
Do not reinvent the wheel.

It is currently the most used plugin for this kind of sites.
Works in modern and old browsers, touch devices and has a good respond to kinetic scrolling in Apple laptops.
It deals with URL hashes, returning links (anchor links), resizing...

Plenty of configurable options, methods and callbacks.

- Highly tested in different devices and browsers by thousands of persons (Windows Phone, Adroid, iOS, touch screen computers, Opera, Safari...)
- Compatibility with touch devices.
- Compatibility with kinetic scrolling (Apple laptops, magic mouse...).
- Compatibility with old browsers (IE 8, Opera 12...).
- Good performance for modern browsers and touch devices (css3).
- Recalculate of sections and slides when resizing the viewport.
- Returning anchors in the URL.
- Responsive mode.
- Accessibility features (keyboard, scroll bar, browser history).
- Use of callbacks to fire actions.
- Plenty of methods and options.

And you get all of that for just 7Kb gzipped if you use fullPage.js.