# Get mouse wheel events in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

Is there a way to get the mouse wheel events (not talking about `scroll` events) in jQuery?

Comment: A quick search turned up [this plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/docs) that may help.

Comment: This solution works for me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154967/jquery-detect-scrolldown

Comment: @thejh posted a new answer on this with DOM3 events: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24707712/2256325

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery scroll() detect when user stops scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144560/jquery-scroll-detect-when-user-stops-scrolling)

Comment: Just a note on this. If you're just wanting to detect changes to an input, and it's not detecting changes via the mouse wheel, try `$(el).on('input', ...`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There's a [plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/) that detects up/down mouse wheel and velocity over a region.

Comment: plugin? come on .. check the answer below you can do it without

Answer (score 223):

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#foo').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
            console.log('scrolling up !');
        }
        else{
            console.log('scrolling down !');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The `DOMMouseScroll` event is used in FF, so you have to to listen on both `.bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel') {` evetns
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMMouseScroll

Comment: `e.originalEvent.wheelDelta` is undefined in FF23

Comment: You don't need to divide by 120 it is useless waste of cpu

Comment: But anyway, why would you want to divide it by 120? What's that constant? (You don't have to, as venimus pointed out.)

Comment: I would recommend the use of the 2nd argument of event handler function - `delta`: `$('#el').on('mousewheel', function(e, delta) { if(delta > 0) { /*up*/ } else { /*down*/ }})`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43468489/1245149).

Comment: `console.log(event.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY > 0 ? "Wheel Up " : "Wheel Down ");`

Comment: @Mojo when I used `delta` it's gives `undefined` with Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: The `mousewheel` event is non-standard and also deprecated. Use `WheelEvent` instead.

Comment: This does work but the problem is if you scroll through touchpad, it creates a lot of scrolls, i.e. for a scroll with touch pad with high speed, multiple screens are scrolled. To solve all such issues, this plugin helped a lot: https://github.com/Promo/wheel-indicator

Answer (score 155):

Binding to both `mousewheel` and `DOMMouseScroll` ended up working really well for me:

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
        // scroll up
    }
    else {
        // scroll down
    }
});
```

This method is working in IE9+, Chrome 33, and Firefox 27.

---

**Edit - Mar 2016**

I decided to revisit this issue since it's been a while. The MDN page for the scroll event has a great way of retrieving the scroll position that makes use of `requestAnimationFrame`, which is highly preferable to my previous detection method. I modified their code to provide better compatibility in addition to scroll direction and position:

```js
(function() {
  var supportOffset = window.pageYOffset !== undefined,
    lastKnownPos = 0,
    ticking = false,
    scrollDir,
    currYPos;

  function doSomething(scrollPos, scrollDir) {
    // Your code goes here...
    console.log('scroll pos: ' + scrollPos + ' | scroll dir: ' + scrollDir);
  }

  window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
    currYPos = supportOffset ? window.pageYOffset : document.body.scrollTop;
    scrollDir = lastKnownPos > currYPos ? 'up' : 'down';
    lastKnownPos = currYPos;

    if (!ticking) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        doSomething(lastKnownPos, scrollDir);
        ticking = false;
      });
    }
    ticking = true;
  });
})();
```

See the Pen [Vanilla JS Scroll Tracking](http://codepen.io/blindside85/pen/bpEMEN/) by Jesse Dupuy ([@blindside85](http://codepen.io/blindside85)) on [CodePen](http://codepen.io).

*This code is currently working in `Chrome v50, Firefox v44, Safari v9, and IE9+`*

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel

Comment: This worked the best for me. However, this script runs per "click" of the scroll wheel. This can be overwhelming for some scripts to use. Is there a way to treat each scroll event as one instance, instead of run the script per scroll wheel click?

Comment: Not especially. From what I've seen, many people will either avoid dealing with scroll tracking, or they'll use a timer instead (e.g. check the user's position on the page every x milliseconds, etc).

If there's a more performant solution out there, I definitely want to know about it!

Comment: I found a way to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919035/using-jquery-to-detect-a-mouse-scroll-per-instance-not-per-click

Comment: @JesseDupuy if a timer is to be used, make sure you *(or who ever is reading this)* is using a queue system for your different "threads". When stacking timers, it has horrible effect on your rendering. I built a script for this case that I'm sharing on github: https://github.com/erik-landvall/animator

Comment: Updated my answer with modern info + Codepen link :)

Comment: How we can cancel twice mousewheel ?

Comment: Are you saying the event is now firing double using my old/new code? Trying to make sure I understand the question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you copy your code into your answer? Never know if codepen might go down someday. [It's happened before.](https://github.com/jsperf/jsperf.com/issues/18#issuecomment-113569132)

Comment: @JesseDupuy, I would upvote this answer, but your updated version doesn`t work if the document fits the view ("width: 100vh; height: 100vh") or got "overflow: hidden;". "window.addEventListener('scroll', callback)" is not the correct answer to "window.addEventListener('mousewheel', callback)".

Comment: Great answer. As @Daniel pointed out, "overflow: hidden" doesn't work with the new version, but the original one works great with it. I needed it for web app that uses mouse scrolling to zoom, and it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 72):

As of now in 2017, you can just write

```
$(window).on('wheel', function(event){

  // deltaY obviously records vertical scroll, deltaX and deltaZ exist too.
  // this condition makes sure it's vertical scrolling that happened
  if(event.originalEvent.deltaY !== 0){

    if(event.originalEvent.deltaY < 0){
      // wheeled up
    }
    else {
      // wheeled down
    }
  }
});
```

Works with current Firefox 51, Chrome 56, IE9+

Comment: This answers works better than all the others!

Comment: `event.originalEvent.deltaY` can be 0 when scrolling horizontally (just tried it in my laptop), so you probably want if `x<0` else if `x>0`.

Answer (score 41):

Answers talking about "mousewheel" event are refering to a deprecated event. The standard event is simply "wheel". See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/wheel

Comment: I tried these and found: "wheel" works in Firefox and IE but not Chrome. "mousewheel" works in Chrome and IE but not Firefox. "DOMMouseScroll" works only in Firefox.

Comment: Looks like Chrome added support for "wheel" in August of 2013: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=227454

Comment: Safari still doesn't support the wheel event.

Comment: As your documentation says, `wheel` event is supported on `Edge`  not `IE` which is not the same thing. [CanIuse](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=wheel)

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me:)

```
 //Firefox
 $('#elem').bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
     if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
         //scroll down
         console.log('Down');
     }else {
         //scroll up
         console.log('Up');
     }

     //prevent page fom scrolling
     return false;
 });

 //IE, Opera, Safari
 $('#elem').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
     if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
         //scroll down
         console.log('Down');
     }else {
         //scroll up
         console.log('Up');
     }

     //prevent page fom scrolling
     return false;
 });
```

[from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154967/jquery-detect-scrolldown)

Answer (score 14):

Here is a vanilla solution. Can be used in jQuery if the event passed to the function is `event.originalEvent` which jQuery makes available as property of the jQuery event. Or if inside the `callback` function under we add before first line: `event = event.originalEvent;`.

This code normalizes the wheel speed/amount and is positive for what would be a forward scroll in a typical mouse, and negative in a backward mouse wheel movement.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BXhzD/

```
var wheel = document.getElementById('wheel');

function report(ammout) {
    wheel.innerHTML = 'wheel ammout: ' + ammout;
}

function callback(event) {
    var normalized;
    if (event.wheelDelta) {
        normalized = (event.wheelDelta % 120 - 0) == -0 ? event.wheelDelta / 120 : event.wheelDelta / 12;
    } else {
        var rawAmmount = event.deltaY ? event.deltaY : event.detail;
        normalized = -(rawAmmount % 3 ? rawAmmount * 10 : rawAmmount / 3);
    }
    report(normalized);
}

var event = 'onwheel' in document ? 'wheel' : 'onmousewheel' in document ? 'mousewheel' : 'DOMMouseScroll';
window.addEventListener(event, callback);
```

There is also a plugin for jQuery, which is more verbose in the code and some extra sugar: https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

Answer (score 8):

This is working in each IE, Firefox and Chrome's latest versions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#whole').bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e){
            if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
                alert("up");
            }
            else{
                alert("down");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

I was stuck in this issue today and found this code is working fine for me

```
$('#content').on('mousewheel', function(event) {
    //console.log(event.deltaX, event.deltaY, event.deltaFactor);
    if(event.deltaY > 0) {
      console.log('scroll up');
    } else {
      console.log('scroll down');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

use this code

```
 knob.bind('mousewheel', function(e){  
 if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
    moveKnob('down');
  } else {
    moveKnob('up');
 }
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The plugin that @DarinDimitrov posted, `jquery-mousewheel`, [is broken with jQuery 3+](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/issues/165). It would be more advisable to use [`jquery-wheel`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-wheel) which works with jQuery 3+.

If you don't want to go the jQuery route, [MDN highly cautions using the `mousewheel` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel) as it's nonstandard and unsupported in many places. It instead says that [you should use the `wheel` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) as you get much more specificity over exactly what the values you're getting mean. It's supported by most major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

my combination looks like this. it fades out and fades in on each scroll down/up. otherwise you have to scroll up to the header, for fading the header in.

```
var header = $("#header");
$('#content-container').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
        if (header.data('faded')) {
            header.data('faded', 0).stop(true).fadeTo(800, 1);
        }
    }
    else{
        if (!header.data('faded')) header.data('faded', 1).stop(true).fadeTo(800, 0);
    }
});
```

the above one is not optimized for touch/mobile, I think this one does it better for all mobile:

```
var iScrollPos = 0;
var header = $("#header");
$('#content-container').scroll(function () {

    var iCurScrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (iCurScrollPos > iScrollPos) {
        if (!header.data('faded')) header.data('faded', 1).stop(true).fadeTo(800, 0);

    } else {
        //Scrolling Up
        if (header.data('faded')) {
            header.data('faded', 0).stop(true).fadeTo(800, 1);
        }
    }
    iScrollPos = iCurScrollPos;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If using mentioned [jquery mousewheel plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel), then what about to use the 2nd argument of event handler function - `delta`:

```
$('#my-element').on('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
    if(delta > 0) {
    console.log('scroll up');
    } 
    else {
    console.log('scroll down');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think many key things are a bit all over the place and I needed to read all the answers to make my code work as I wanted, so I will post my findings in just one place:

- You should use `"wheel"` event over the other deprecated or browser specific events.
- Many people here is getting something wrong: the opposite of `x>0` is `x<=0` and the opposite of `x<0` is `x>=0`, many of the answers in here will trigger scrolling down or up incorrectly when `x=0` (horizontal scrolling).
- Someone was asking how to put sensitivity on it, for this you can use `setTimeout()` with like 50 ms of delay that changes some helper flag `isWaiting=false` and you protect yourself with `if(isWaiting)` then don't do anything. When it fires you manually change `isWaiting=true` and just below this line you start the **setTimeout** again who will later change `isWaiting=false` after 50 ms.

Answer (score -3):

I got same problem recently where
`$(window).mousewheel` was returning `undefined`

What I did was `$(window).on('mousewheel', function() {});`

Further to process it I am using:

```
function (event) {
    var direction = null,
        key;

    if (event.type === 'mousewheel') {
        if (yourFunctionForGetMouseWheelDirection(event) > 0) {
            direction = 'up';
        } else {
            direction = 'down';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not say what has newUtilities.getMouseWheelDirection

Comment: It's out of scope of this question. SO it's not copy paste website.