# jquery one-scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using the jQuery.ScrollTo library right now like this to go directly to different selectors on the page:

```
var content = [$('#first'), $('#second'), $('#third'), $('#fourth'), $('#fifth')];
var idNumber = 0;
var max = content.length - 1;
$('#down').click(function () {
    if (idNumber < max) {
        idNumber += 1;
        $('div').scrollTo(content[idNumber], 1000);
    }
});
$('#up').click(function () {
    if (idNumber >= 1) {
        idNumber -= 1;
        $('div').scrollTo(content[idNumber], 1000);
    }
});
```

but what I want instead of triggering the event from a button I want the same effect with a one scroll, exactly like this page:
http://www.myprovence.fr/#p_home

Comment: look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189840/get-mouse-wheel-events-in-jquery there u will find how to use mouse scroll events with jquery

Comment: @x4rf41 that's a great plugin, thanks! but I just want to trigger one event not several, which is the case now with the .mousewheel(). Something like a callback when the one scrollTo event is done?