# jquery animated horizontal scroll on mouse scroll event

Tags: jquery, css, html, horizontal-scrolling, mousewheel

I have been working on this animated horizontal offset for div, on `mousescroll` event.
Here is the link for what I've done till now, could somebody see what I'm doing wrong?

The animation happens on the click action i need the same for mousescroll.
http://jsfiddle.net/laksdesign/WvRR6/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".scroll").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#wrapper').animate({ scrollLeft: $('#wrapper').scrollLeft() + $(this.hash).offset().left }, 800);
    });

    $('body').bind('mousewheel', function(scroll){
        if(scroll.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
            scroll.preventDefault();
            $('#wrapper').animate({ scrollLeft: $('#wrapper').scrollLeft() + $(this.hash).offset().left }, 800);
        } else{

        }
    });
});
```

There is another reference which I took the animation based on mousescroll is:
http://jsfiddle.net/laksdesign/EATaU/

Comment: You need this script: https://raw.github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/master/jquery.mousewheel.js

Comment: @Dom I believe there are dozens of scripts the user can use, correct?

Comment: @Evan I know, just giving him an example of one.

Comment: @Dom I was only asking to ensure what I wrote below was correct, not to "shoot down" your comment. Thanks

Comment: @Evan from what I know, there are others, however, the one I provided is most widely used. But your answer is definitely valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to capture the `mousescroll` event in jQuery you will need to use a plugin or some external function. I would suggest using a plugin rather than reinventing the wheel. Notice how in the reference you've provided the fiddle is using a `mousewheel.js` file - that's the plugin you'll need to use.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189866/973578) for some more information on how to use the plugin

An example plugin you could use:

- [**BrandonAaron.com**](https://www.google.com/search?q=brandonAaron%20mousewheel&aq=f&oq=brandonAaron%20mousewheel&aqs=chrome.0.64j0l3j60j62.6277j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - I am not allowed to link to this site, so Google it instead.

You would use the plugin as so:

```
// using bind
$('#my_elem').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
    console.log(delta);
});
```

As the user `@Dom` suggested in the comment above, another widely used plugin is:

- [**jQuery Mousewheel**](https://raw.github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/master/jquery.mousewheel.js)

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply.
I did try that out initially which dint seem to go in the right direction of my taught for the divs to animate.

But the link below on jsfiddle is the right one which im looking for , with the animate happening horizontally with mousescroll currently it happnes to be a vertical scroll

http://jsfiddle.net/laksdesign/EATaU/1/

Comment: @user2283274 I get a 404 on that link - are you saying that it's still not functioning correctly for you? What's the issue?

Comment: Hey Evan thanks for the reply and i figured out the way to get what i had been looking for. Here is a link with the final version http://jsfiddle.net/laksdesign/kmABb/