# Zoom in/out events in jQuery

Tags: jquery, zooming

I simply want a function that show alert on zoom in window saying like "you zoomed in" and on zoom out saying like "you zoomed out", I searched for this function for lot of time but every time I search I get like "zooming into window event" and that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you mean zooming in, like using Ctrl +?

Answer (score 9):

> srceen.width is fixed value but where as window.innerWidth value will change as per the zoom effect. please try the below code:

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
       if(screen.width == window.innerWidth){
           alert("you are on normal page with 100% zoom");
       } else if(screen.width > window.innerWidth){
           alert("you have zoomed in the page i.e more than 100%");
       } else {
           alert("you have zoomed out i.e less than 100%")
       }
    });
```

Comment: Very good job! I was looking for it all day! Very nice and neat.

Answer (score 1):

rather than getting any zoom function
use jquery

```
.resize()
```

function

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by zooming in but i am gonna guess it's Ctrl + Mouse Wheel movement.

In order to implement that, simply look for the mouse wheel event and check if the control key is down.

Here is a starting point: [Get mouse wheel events in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189840/get-mouse-wheel-events-in-jquery)

This will allow you to detect if the mouse is scrolling up or down.

All you need to add is an IF inside to check if the ctrl key is pressed and you will be able to detect if the user is zooming

Comment: They can achieve the same thing with a ctrl + or ctrl - as well