# Detect scrolling on pages without a scroll bar

Tags: javascript, css

I have a webpage where the body has css

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

I do not want to show the scroll bar.

I want to run some javascript when the user scrolls down, so I did this:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("scroll", function (e) {
    console.log("scrolling engage");
    if (e.detail > 0) {
        // do things ...
    }
    return false;
}, true);
</script>
```

I also tried setting `onscroll` to the function. The problem is that this event does not fire, I then found [this page](http://help.dottoro.com/ljurkcpe.php) which says the event only fires when there is a scroll bar, however I don't want a scroll bar.

How do I detect the scroll wheel without showing the scroll bar? [I do not want to use jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18748082/1704411).

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll

Comment: I know you don't want to use jQuery, but a good place to start figuring out how to do it is to look at the [jQuery mousewheel source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/blob/master/jquery.mousewheel.js) which will contain all manner of plain javascript solutions to detecting crossbrowser mousewheel events.

Comment: How do you expect to scroll? using the mouse?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Yes, I want to detect the scroll wheel on the mouse.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> EDIT: The previous version of this answer was for the `mousewheel` event that is non-standard/deprecated. Use the `wheel` event instead. Notice that in this case, the value of `deltaY` is opposite to the one of `wheelDeltaY` so instead of adding, you'll substract.

You can use the `wheel` event. Once that event is called, it has the Delta values that will show you how many pixels the mousewheel scrolled. Although you'll be interested only in the `deltaY` one.

Now, once you have the vertical change, you just need to update the translation of the body by updating the value of `transform:translateY` and substracting the `e.deltaY` value to it. Something like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {

    // get the old value of the translation (there has to be an easier way than this)
    var oldVal = parseInt(document.getElementById("body").style.transform.replace("translateY(","").replace("px)",""));

    // to make it work on IE or Chrome
    var variation = parseInt(e.deltaY);
    
    // update the body translation to simulate a scroll
    document.getElementById("body").style.transform = "translateY(" + (oldVal - variation) + "px)";

    return false;
    
}, true);
```

```css
body {
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

```html
<body id="body" style="transform:translateY(0px)">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
  <p>9</p>
  <p>10</p>
  <p>11</p>
  <p>12</p>
  <p>13</p>
  <p>14</p>
  <p>15</p>
  <p>16</p>
  <p>17</p>
  <p>18</p>
  <p>19</p>
  <p>20</p>
</body>
```

It is difficult to see the effect on that window, You can see it better on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pLb93eeL/4/

Comment: A small note I'd like to add for Qt developers is that Qt5 uses a WebKit that works with `mousewheel` event and `wheelDeltaY` property. I then was able to make a horizontal scroller react to `wheelDeltaY`. This answer helped me, however.

Comment: Wheel event wont work in mobile or in any touch screen, how to do it there