# Use jQuery to check mousewheel event without scrollbar

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollbar, mousewheel

How to check mousewheel movement without scrollbar?

```
$(document).mousewheel(function() {
     clicker.html("a7a");
});
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I highly recommend you use this jQuery plugin: [PLUGIN](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/)

Without a plugin, try this example: [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CvCc6/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id='foo' style='height:300px; width:300px; background-color:red'></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#foo').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
        alert('up');
    } else {
        alert('down');
    }
});
```

There is no scrollbar on the div but the wheel event is detected.

Comment: So it seems that `wheelDelta` comes out to either `120` or `-120` so division normalizes this value - but does anyone know why the browser chooses 120 as the value?

Comment: I would recommend the use of the 2nd argument of event handler function - `delta`: `$('#el').on('mousewheel', function(e, delta) { if(delta > 0) { /*up*/ } else { /*down*/ }})`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43468489/1245149).

Comment: So what is the puprose of the jquery-mousewheel plugin if the event can be handled without it?

Answer (score 9):

use this code

```
$('#foo').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {           
     if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
          //up
     }
     else {
          //down
     }
});
```

Comment: This answer would be much better if it included more explanation as to how it works, especially as there is already an upvoted answer present.

Comment: The example works fine, but the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel) says to use the `'wheel'` event instead of `'mousewheel'`.

Answer (score 7):

And, if you don't want to use any plugin at all (IE8, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera...), just do this:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler(), false);
    document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler(), false);
} else {
    sq.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler());
}


function MouseWheelHandler() {
    return function (e) {
        // cross-browser wheel delta
        var e = window.event || e;
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));

        //scrolling down?
        if (delta < 0) {
            alert("Down");
        }

        //scrolling up?
        else {
             alert("Up");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/CvCc6/1/

Answer (score 2):

This is just an update to @Aaron's answer, using the new "wheel" event, described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel

```
$('#foo').on('wheel', function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
        console.log('scrolling up !');
    } else{
        console.log('scrolling down !');
    }
});
```

You can also use `deltaX` to see horizontal scroll, or `deltaZ` if you've got some crazy 3D thing going on.