# jquery pan with mousemove and zoom with mousewheel plugin

Tags: jquery, image, scroll, parallax, mousemove

I have searched for the plugin that I need but couldn't solve my problem. I have images on the page and I need to make the clicked image to enlarge to fill whole the viewport ant fit to one side  of the screen either horizontal or vertical plane. I am creating a div element and append it to the body. I am putting an additional div conatining an image element with proper src taken by the clicked element data sources. Images are either horizontal or vertical. most of the time they are needed to be fill to width of the viewport and height will be overflow:hidden. I want to scroll to bottom to see the bottom of the image and  if it is desired it is needed to be zoomable. At zoomed in position I need to be able to pan in horizontally and verticaly. Some images maybe will be smaller than the viewport I am scaling them to with the width.

I tried the jparallax plugin it seems to work but I couldn't add any extra button form next and previosu buttons. I used some zoom plugins like imgViewer it is also seems to work enough. But when I zoom the image the scoll/pan plugin does not update its values to adapt the situation while it is not designed for this.

How can ı solve this problem.

Thansk for your atteniton.

Comment: Have you read the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880159/use-jquery-to-check-mousewheel-event-without-scrollbar)?

Comment: I didn't. I have no problem with mousewheel I think. I am able to zoom in-out the image with imgViewer. But I can't do the paning with mousemove event with the zoom action. JParallax loses the proper data required for it after the zoom in-out action.

Comment: Try making a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate what's working and what's not. That will give people here a start point.

Comment: How I will upload addtional plugins to js fiddler ? :/ I have some hurry for this task :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p3okLxLs/2/   this is the jsfiddler without external libraries like mousewheel imgViewer Jparallax event.frame all them jquery libs.

Comment: I need to fit the image with respect to width and scroll by mouse up and down movement. It is needed to be zoomabln. Thus when I zoom in I need to be able to move the mouse to left or right to see the rest of the image and zoor out which is limited to screen width or height which one is smaller it will decide the fitting which is the minimum zoom condition.