# How to check scroll top or bottom without using scrollTop?

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

Hi is there a way to check if there is a way to check mousewheel event up or down without checking where it last scrolled. As I have disabled my scrolling and used animate instead of scroll.

```
var currentTop = 0;    
var scrolling = false;
var allowNextAnimation = true;

$('.contactDiv').on('scroll touchmove mousewheel', function(e){
if (!scrolling && allowNextAnimation) {

    if (scrollTop)
       currentTop = currentTop + 70;
    else if (scrollDown)
       currentTop = currentTop - 70;
    scrolling = true;
    $('.contactDiv').animate({
        scrollTop: currentTop
    }, 500, function(){
        scrolling = false;
        allowNextAnimation = false;
    });

    return false;
}
allowNextAnimation = true;
});
```

I need some way to know if the mouse scrolls up or down without knowing where scrollTop is. Any advice?

Comment: For mousewhell, check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880159/use-jquery-to-check-mousewheel-event-without-scrollbar . For swipe events I suggest you to use http://hammerjs.github.io/ . If you are interested I can explain to you in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For mousewheel event:

```
$('html, body').on('mousewheel MozMousePixelScroll', function (event) {
    var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1
                  || event.originalEvent.detail;
    if(delta < 0){
        console.log('scroll up');
    } else {
        console.log('scroll down');
    }
});
```

You can see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/1vb8yh0L/1/) on jsFiddle that blocks mousewheel scroll for 300 ms if middle container reached top/bottom and you continue scrolling mousewheel up/down. After 300 ms of inactivity you can scroll document.

For touch event track pageY event property