# Get each scroll and increment active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel

I want to make a custom slider on mousewheel event, my question is how can i do for get each scroll done on my page and add an active class on my 'ul li' and increment it one by one like:

```js
if ($('scroll') === 1, function() {
  $('ul li:first-child').addClass('active');
});
if ($('scroll') === 2, function() {
  $('ul li:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
ul li{
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  background:blue;
  margin:5px;
  list-style:none
  }

ul li.active{
  background:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What on earth is this strange syntax you are trying to use? Step 1 would be to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18880270/2887133) , you can do something like this:

```js
var scrollable = $('ul li').length - 1,
  count = 0;
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
    if (scrollable >= count && count > 0) {
      $('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
      count--
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    if (scrollable > count) {
      $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
      count++
    } else {
      return false;
    }

  }
})
```

```css
ul li {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  list-style: none
}
ul li.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This syntax doesn't work:

```
if (value === other value, function() {

});
```

The correct syntax for an `if` statement is as follows:

```
if (value === other value) {
    // execute code in here
}
```

Also, you've got this:

```
$('scroll') === 1
```

Here, `$('scroll')` is a jQuery function that selects the `<scroll>` HTML element (which doesn't exist).

Instead, you can detect the page's scroll position in JavaScript using `window.scrollY`, which returns [the number of pixels that the document is currently scrolled down from the top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY). For example:

```
if (window.scrollY < 100) {
    $('ul li:first-child').addClass('active');
} else if (window.scrollY < 200) {
    $('ul li:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but there is no possibilities to get each time the user scroll in the page ? not in pixel but just everytime he use his mousewheel? i think your solution can' t work if the body overflow is hidden

Comment: You can [add an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for the ["scroll" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll).