# if scroll, go top?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

eg. If the user uses his scroll to go back up ^ from a lower section of my website, i want him to be bounced back all the way. and not being able to stay midway of the website.

an easy jquery easing function with a scroll function attached to it. Does anyone consume the knowledge of that in here, if so: i would be very greatfull!

Have a nice day, greetings.

Comment: Try Googling the part of the text above that describes your problem: [*easy jquery easing function with a scroll function*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=easy+jquery+easing+function+with+a+scroll+function)

Comment: If you're looking to use the mouse wheel for events, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189840/get-mouse-wheel-events-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in all browsers:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false); //IE9, Chrome, Safari, Oper
        document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false); //Firefox
    } else {
        document.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler); //IE 6/7/8
    }


   function MouseWheelHandler(){

        // cross-browser wheel delta
        e = window.event || e;
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));

        //scrolling up?
        if (delta >= 0) {
            $('body').scrollTop(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @Joel please see my answer again. I forgot it didn't work in Firefox. I've updated it with the correct solution. Also if you find it useful please accept it :)

Comment: Hi again, yes it works very good. i've tried it cross-browser wise and it seems to work fine (even in IE ^^ ). However, i'm not sure what I'm doing wrong when I apply .animate({},2000);

any ideas why it wont work?

Comment: however, now since ur last update. there seems to be an error on line 21. I've tried to locate the incorrect closing tag but i'm unable to find it. :/

Comment: @Joel try it again, The second `)` at the end was wrong should be a `}`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, i removed it a few seconds ago. Thanks again for the great support! However, when i try to apply an animate function to : $('body').scrollTop(0); it doesnt work. here's what I've written: $('body').scrollTop(0).animate({},2000);
Thanks again for your expertise!

Comment: Scrolling down works for some odd reason.... (with the code that you posted)

Comment: @Joel what do you mean with "scrolling down works"? If you add yoru code inside the condition `delta>=0` it will only work on scrolling up with the mousewheel. Take a look a this living example: http://jsfiddle.net/8Lj5S/1/

Answer (score 0):

try something:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('mousewheel', function(e){
      if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) { // if scrolling towards up
          $('body').scrollTop(0);
      }          
   });
});
```

Comment: That also works scrolling down...

Comment: That doesn't work on Firefox

Comment: I am very thankfull for your answer (solution) Zaheer.
Even if it didnt work 100% perhaps you could help me with implementing a animate solution on Alvaro's answer (since I cannot get it to work)
greetings.

Comment: @Zaheer Scrolling down works for some odd reason.... (with the code that you posted)