# Javascript scrolling event without scrollable frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, scroll

I have a webpage and I want it to alert 'hello world' if the user scrolls, BUT there is no scrollable frame (sort of a javascript/jquery event $(document).onmousewheeluse(); ). Is there a way to do this or should I hide a scrollable div somewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189840/get-mouse-wheel-events-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
```

will call the function `MouseWheelHandler` when scrolled.