# Any way to scroll iframe even if the cursor isn't hovering it?

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll

Maybe you could make a javascript that scrolls the iframe on scrollwheel event? I'm not really that good at javascript though.

I found this, but I still don't know how to target the iframe and scroll it:
[Get mouse wheel events in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189840/get-mouse-wheel-events-in-jquery)

Comment: Is the iframe on the same origin? Origin = scheme/host/port, so `https://example.com` can only control an iframe on `https://example.com`

Comment: Then you can. With JS, catching the mousewheel event in the top document and change the scroll offset in the frame document. But I'm going to bed. Goodluck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are : http://jsfiddle.net/dsmeuzL5/

HTML :

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="//www.yourpage.com"></iframe>
```

JS : 
    var iframe = document.getElementById('myframe');

```
var MouseWheelHandler = function (e) {
    // cross-browser wheel delta
    var e = window.event || e; // old IE support
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
    console.log(delta);
    var doc = iframe.contentDocument ? iframe.contentDocument : (iframe.contentWindow ? iframe.contentWindow.document : iframe.document);
    doc.body.scrollTop = doc.body.scrollTop - (delta * 30);

    return false;
}


if (window.addEventListener) {
    // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    window.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
    // Firefox
    window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
}
// IE 6/7/8
else window.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);
```

Comment: Just read the code so that next time you can make it yourself :)

Comment: My mouse scrolls 100px per scroll. Yours only 30. Is there a way to sync that? Normal scrolling speed would be awesome.

Comment: I do not think so. Maybe you should not be able to do it because its is based on OS values. I do not know.