# How to turn Bootstrap Carousel slides to change on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [bootstrap carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) in my website. But I want its functionality little different. I want slides to change on mouseScroll (each slide on each time mouse scrolled).

How can I achieve it with Bootstrap Carousel?

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 3000
});
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mA6Za/93/)**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$('#myCarousel').carousel('next')` slides to next item as [documented](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel).
So you can bind scroll event to do that:

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('mousewheel', function() {
    $(this).carousel('next');
});
```

Edit: [you can get mouse wheel events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189840/get-mouse-wheel-events-in-jquery#answer-15629039) and make carousel move to next or previous slide:

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
        $(this).carousel('next');
    } else {
        $(this).carousel('prev');
    }
});
```

updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mA6Za/94/)

You can also bind it to all carousels instead of a specific single one by using a class selector: Use `$('.carousel').bind(...)` for that. If your requirement is to have *all* your carousels support the mouse wheel, not just a specific single one, the class selector is more convenient.

Comment: `mousewheel` works in Chrome 58, however, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel , the event is deprecated and should be replaced with [wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) event, which supports more browsers. updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mA6Za/457/). Also I noticed the wheel direction is different between `wheel` and `mousewheel` events.