# how to use window.scroll function to scroll through slides?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://codepen.io/mikun/pen/YWgqEX this is a link to what I am working with. 
Here is what I have added to the JS file:

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
  console.log(e);
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
 });
```

not quite too sure how else to go about this. Again, just want the user to be able to scroll through the slides up and down using their mouse/trackpad

Comment: similar to how this is done: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html#firstPage

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529361/how-to-turn-bootstrap-carousel-slides-to-change-on-scroll