# How to count mouse wheel scroll in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to count mouse scroll in jquery/javascript?
Like initial value 0 and scroll down ++1 and scroll up --1.
And not be -1. Must be positive.

If i scroll 2 times down then value will be 2 and then scroll one time up then value be 1.

Comment: This [Get mouse wheel events in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189840/get-mouse-wheel-events-in-jquery) has some useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution for your question

```
var scrollCount = 0, 
    latestScrollTop = 0,
    doc = document.documentElement,
    top = 0;

// Bind window scroll event
$(window).bind('scroll', function (e) {
    top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop)  - (doc.clientTop || 0);

    if (latestScrollTop < top) {
        // Scroll down, increment value
        scrollCount += 1;
    } else {
        // Scroll up, decrement value
        scrollCount -= 1;
    }

    // Store latest scroll position for next position calculation
    latestScrollTop = top;
});
```

Comment: new value will store in top after scroll?
am i right?
// Store latest scroll position for next position calculation

Comment: To determine if we scrolled up or down, we need to store this value for next verification. The value you need for the amount of scrolls is `scrollCount`.

Comment: `latestScrollTop` gives you the amount of pixels you scrolled within the browser. `scrollCount` is incremental variable by 1, something you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scrollPos = 0;
    var Counter = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollPosCur = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scrollPosCur > scrollPos) {
            Counter -= 1;
        } else {
            Counter += 1;
        }
        scrollPos = scrollPosCur;
    });
});
```

The code compares the position of a scrollbar. `scrollPos` shows how many pixels you moved the scrollbar downwards and is initialized with a value of `0`, as it starts at the top.

When you scroll the page, `scrollPosCur` will first save the current Position of the scrollbar. After that we compare how the value changed :

If the current value is bigger than the saved one, it indicates that the scrollbar has been moved downwards, so your `Counter` is incremented by `1`.
Analogous to that, we decrement the `Counter` by `1` when `scrollPosCur` is smaller than `scrollPos`.

In order to keep the code working, we save the current value to compare against for future scroll Events.

Comment: what this think do : (scrollPosCur > scrollPos)?

Comment: @JasjeetSingh : Finalized the answer.

Comment: thanks it works for me. @Mike Vranckx's answer is also worked.

Comment: You could upvote both and mark your favourite approved.

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollcount=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").scroll(function(){
    $("span").text(scrollcount+=1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);
        return false;
    });
```