# detecting scroll direction inside element with overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following css

```
body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

I am still able to detect scoll event using jquery.

```
$('body').on("mousewheel", function() {
      alert($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

This gives 0 every time because of `overflow:hidden`

what i want is to detect the direction of scroll (up or down).

I cant use

```
var previousScroll = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(){
   var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (currentScroll > previousScroll){
       alert('down');
   } else {
      alert('up');
   }
   previousScroll = currentScroll;
});
```

because scrollTop is always 0.

Is there a way?

Comment: Try see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189840/get-mouse-wheel-events-in-jquery

Comment: That is exactly what i was searching for. thanks