# Scroll to element when user scrolls from top down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I am trying to do a effect like on the [App Builder Website](http://www.apps-builder.com/).
When the user is at the header with the background image/video and scrolls down, the site scrolls down to the next div/section/etc. .
 
If the user scrolls back up and the image/video part is reached, the page scrolls to the top of it.
 I have tried the following code but there is bug i can't find:

```
function scrollto(where){
   $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(where).offset().top - 65}, 800);
   console.log('Scrolled to ' + where);
   closeMenue();
}


var lastScrollTop = 0;
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).scroll(function(event){
var st = $(this).scrollTop();
if (st > lastScrollTop){  
  if (scroll == 0){
    scrollto('.about');
  }
  else{
  }
} else {  
  if (scroll == 530){
    scrollto('.parallax'); 
  }
  else{
  }
}
lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

**It is working fine, but only once.** Is there a Plugin I can use?
Sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: Yep, that site is using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) as you can see from their code.

Comment: Seems your code could be simplified : `if (st > lastScrollTop) scrollto('.about'); else scrollto('.parallax');`. Are you sure the second section is always  *exactly*  at 530 pix offset? In any case, you shouldn't really need to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you posted is making use of [fullPage.js plugin](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

It works using CSS3 transitions with a fallback to jQuery when needed.

If you don't want to use jQuery, there's even a [pure javascript version](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/pure%20javascript%20(Alpha)) for it in development but functional.

Comment: Thank you! It is a really nice Plugin! I am going to use it

Answer (score 0):

dont use jquery for smooth transitions. 
is better do that things with css methods.

check [this](http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/) if want use any library

Answer (score 0):

So, here's what I believe I'm seeing on their site if you want to do something similar:

1. No scroll bar; you'll need to make your top-most container have overflow: hidden. It might be best to capture scroll wheel events. See here for more details: [Get mouse wheel events in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189840/get-mouse-wheel-events-in-jquery)
2. The active viewport gets a class "active". They're presumably using it to keep track of which viewport to scroll to next and maybe to determine

So, in your scroll wheel event handler, you'll need to:

1. Determine first if you're going up or down. (Outlined in the SO link above)
2. You'll need to find the next sibling div/viewport/container/whatever that's not active.
3. You'll want to move the active class to that appropriate sibling (previous/next depending on up/down) and scroll it into view using scrollTop.