# Prevent scroll event triggered when content push at top

Tags: jquery

I noticed that jquery scroll event automatically triggered when some content push at the top of the page by ajax.
Any expert know how to avoid scroll event being triggered when the content has been added? But scroll event triggered when user run the mousewheel, page up down as well as keyboard up and down probably?

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
        console.log("User manual scrolled.");
    });
```

Based on this example.
https://jsfiddle.net/q00jnv4n/

Comment: Which jQuery version? I don't see this behavior in the jQuery 2.1.3  -- https://jsfiddle.net/ndnz8v79/

Comment: jquery 2.1.1 version.

Comment: based on this example, it seems will trigger the event either in 2.1.1 or 2.1.3 version.
https://jsfiddle.net/q00jnv4n/

Comment: It's because of that line `$(window).scrollTop(divHeight);` in `AddContent()` function

Comment: Ok.. so means content push on top won't trigger the event, but scrollTop will trigger that event hence it become like a rubberband.

Comment: @Mah Jin Khai: Can you please clarify your overall aim, rather than just trying to "prevent scroll event"? The question is not clear as written as you are focusing on only one detail of the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`.off` function used to **Remove an event handler.**

You should be using `$(window).off("scroll")` just before loading content by ajax and then again use  `$(window).on('scroll', function () {` after loading the content

By using `.off` your scroll handler will be remove while content is being loaded on site.

Answer (score 0):

One option to stop the display *appearing to move* is to adjust the `scrollTop` by the amount the `#result` div has changed in height e.g. `scrollTop = (scrollTop + newHeight - oldHeight)`:

```
function AddContent() {
    var height = $('#result').height();
    console.log("height: " + height);
    $(".UnloadedPara").each(function () {
        //console.log();
        $(this).replaceWith("<div>This is some new paragraph</div>");
    });

    var newHeight = $('#result').height();
    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + newHeight - height);
}
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/q00jnv4n/12/

Comment: this is not the answer OP is looking for.

Comment: @Shoaib Shakeel: In that case: I am glad *you* understand the question (which it not clear). Perhaps you can clarify it?

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop` fires an event 'scroll' when called. OP wants to suppress this event in case `Add Content` button is clicked.

Comment: @Shoaib Shakeel: Sounds like an X-Y question to me. I would prefer to hear the OPs overall aim, rather than one specific detail they think they need. I will ask them for clarification :)

Comment: Thanks everyone. i got some workaround for this, will post later, because i am busy with something right now.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `window.scrollTop()` in your code. It will automatically trigger scroll event in `jQuery` as `jQuery` uses `window.scrollTo()` under the hood.

You cannot suppress 'scroll' event fired by this. But you can use a hack to detect if scroll event was called after you 'AddContent' called `window.scrollTop()`. You can do it by setting a boolean variable in your `AddContent` to `false`. And check in your scroll event handler if the variable if `false` or not. If it is `false` then set it to `true` and don't do anything. Otherwise perform you desired action.

I forked your jsfiddle and updated it: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xe1wgxsz/)

Answer (score 0):

referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189840/get-mouse-wheel-events-in-jquery) post, there exists an event only listening to **mouse**scroll.

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
        // scroll up
    } else {
        // scroll down
    }
});
```

greetings timotheus

Answer (score 0):

This is merely a workaround, but if you need a quick fix you can have the window scroll back to the button after the new content has been loaded at the top.
https://jsfiddle.net/msfq5mx0/

```
$(window).scrollTo(0,$("#btnAddContent").offset().top);
```