# Stopping manual scroll -- forcing scroll to a particular point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there an easy way to capture the user's scroll event (either mousewheel, touch event, or cursor keys) so that the website scrolls to a particular point instead.

I don't know what it's called, but this site does it: http://bit.ly/1JMYyGE

You try and scroll down and the view is scrolled to a new section, rather than allowing the user to stop mid-section.

Comment: try jQuery `.keyup()`, maybe

Comment: Maybe this question could help you: _http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189840/get-mouse-wheel-events-in-jquery_

Comment: check out: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Answer (score 3):

This page is using anchors to direct the screen to a specific location. You can see what location that is in the url it comes right after the hash #page-1 for example. [anchor tag](http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html) this site could help with setting up anchor tag.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, it's usually done with anchors and a bit of js / jquery for smooth scrolling: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like one page scroll such as [these](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html) [plugins](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Answer (score 0):

The procedure usually is solved by emulating the scroll behaviour. Make the site

```
html, body {overflow:hidden;}
```

And have your individual "pages" as 100% width/height containers that you animate with JS and/or CSS3 transitions. I'd recommend using hardware-accelerated transitions to increase performance. That is, take a look at `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` for CSS.

So animating to page X from page Y: Place page X outside viewport and animate it to a y-value of 0, whilst animating page Y in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

http://jsbin.com/wukigajegu/2/edit?html,js,console,output

What you actually want to do will vary depending on how your page is set up.