# How to scroll to a specific div when the mouse is scrolled with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code right now which scrolls to the correct place when a button is clicked:

```
$("#skills").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#skills_page").offset().top}, 500);
    $(this).addClass("toggled_alt");
    $("#skills_id").css("background-color", "#646464");
    $("#contact_id, #home_id, #about_id").css("background-color", "transparent");
    $("#home, #contact, #about").removeClass("toggled");
    $("#home, #contact, #about").removeClass("toggled_alt");
});
```

What I want to do now is I want the page to scroll to the next div when the scroll wheel is moved down/up. I've been searching google for a while now and all that comes up is stuff about smooth scrolling which is not what I want. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ I did that on my site with this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22518932/3923426) and it's comments, and the [MDN page on the wheel event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel).

Looks like you can bind to the event like this:

```
$(window).on('wheel', function(event){
```

But that might be overwhelming as it's each "click" of the mousewheel.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z52bq1xn/). Only tested in Chrome.

Comment: Maybe with some conditional logic you could make this work. Is there a specific DomMouseScroll for up/down?