# Get direction for mousewheel JQuery event handler

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

I try to figure out which direction the user have "mousewheeled" using a binding on a `mousewheel` event for my element.

You can see in the following snippet, when mousewheeling your mouse over the grey rectangle, the event is triggered.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qexb1207/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="rect"></div>
<div>
    Mousewheel event state : 
    <label class="event-state-mousewheel">Triggered !</label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.rect {
    width : 200px;
    height : 200px;
    background-color : lightgrey;
}

.event-state-mousewheel {
    color : red;
    display : none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $('.rect').on('mousewheel', function(event) {
        $(".event-state-mousewheel").stop(true, false).fadeIn(250).fadeOut(250);
    });
});
```

**PROBLEM**

I cannot find a way to get the direction. I tryied to debug the object returned when the event is triggered, but it is way too big to debug since the amount of element in it is monstruous.

**QUESTION**

Is there a formula using these element (from the object returned) to get the mousewheel direction ?
Or is there an event like `$("#element").on("mousewheeltop")` ?

**NOTE**

I want at possible not use any other external plugin, only JQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The properties wheelDelta and detail are what you need, as below:

```
if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
    // Scroll up
}
else {
    // Scroll down
}
```

I've updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qexb1207/1/) with this code.

Also, note that the **mousewheel** event is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) and you should use **wheel** instead.

Comment: After changing `.mousewheel` to `.wheel`, the alert always returns `down`, even when scrolling up.

Comment: @TimLewis I don't see this behaviour in this updated jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/qexb1207/2/

Comment: Hmm... What browser are you using? I notice `down` only in Firefox, but Chrome shows the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#foo').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
            $(this).text('scrolling up !');
        }
        else{
            $(this).text('scrolling down !');
        }
    });
});
```

Watch this : [Get mouse wheel events in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189840/get-mouse-wheel-events-in-jquery)

Comment: @AlanBuchanan You are right it doesn't need to. I edit