# How to detect mouse scroll down in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I am using jQuery 2.0.2. I am able to detect scrolling up mousewheel by using

```
Panel.bind("mousewheel", function () {});
```

How to detect mouse scrolling down?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154967/jquery-detect-scrolldown

Comment: why not use https://api.jquery.com/scroll/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mousewheel event returns a delta value, signifying if the mouse wheel was scrolled up or down.

Here's a very good site explaining how to handle mousewheel events in all browsers (Firefox seems to do it a little differently than others):

http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/

There's also a jQuery plugin:

https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [jQuery Mouse Wheel Plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/)

> In order to use the plugin, simply bind the mousewheel event to an
>   element. It also provides two helper methods called **mousewheel** and
>   **unmousewheel** that act just like other event helper methods in jQuery.
>   The event callback receives three extra arguments which are the
>   normalized "deltas" of the mouse wheel.