# How To Scroll down 100% with Mousewheel at once ? - jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm creating a OnePage for my Portfolio.

Each site fills 100% of the Screen. And I want that when I use the Mouse-wheel to scroll, that one Scroll, scrolls down 100%, so that I come directly to the next site and not somewhere between the pages.

Can someone tell me how I can solve this problem with JS/jQuery?

Comment: you could animate the `.scrollTop()` to the next site. Can you share some markup or fiddle link?

Comment: That's what I meant :) share some code please

Comment: @badZoke a basic fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JqU2T/

Comment: I'll post the code in a few hours, at the moment i'm at work and got no access to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use the following onscroll handler, it's based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154967/jquery-detect-scrolldown#11746221):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('.mydiv');
    var dir = 'up'; // wheel scroll direction
    var div = 0; // current div
    $(document.body).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            dir = 'down';
        } else {
            dir = 'up';
        }
        // find currently visible div :
        div = -1;
        divs.each(function(i){
            if (div<0 && ($(this).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop())) {
                div = i;
            }
        });
        if (dir == 'up' && div > 0) {
            div--;
        }
        if (dir == 'down' && div < divs.length) {
            div++;
        }
        $('html,body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: divs.eq(div).offset().top
        }, 200);
        return false;
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('html,body').scrollTop(divs.eq(div).offset().top);
    });
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JqU2T/5/) and its [separated test page](http://jsfiddle.net/JqU2T/5/show).

Comment: Thanks, I am glad it helped ;-) And also updated the answer, so now it works better also with scrollbars. Greetings

Comment: $('html,body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: divs.eq(div).offset().top
        }, 200);,in this code am getting top is undefined or null reference,could u help me?

Answer (score 1):

MouseWheel is not a default event within jQuery, so to start with you would need [something like this](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) and either write your own function to switch to the next page or use another plugin like [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Not quite sure whether or not that is best practice though..

**EDIT**

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/harpax/t45S8/1/) on the base of Stano's fiddle.

```
$("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (delta > 0 && current_page > 0) {
        current_page = current_page - 1;
        $("body").scrollTo( '#page_'+current_page);  
    } else if (delta < 0 && current_page < 10) {
        current_page = current_page + 1;
        $("body").scrollTo( '#page_'+current_page);
    }
});
```

and another edit: the fiddle only works in FF as Chrome and IE refuse to load the scripts because of the wrong MIME-Type..

Comment: If I use the first Plugin, can i Just Say DeltaY = 100% or how should i do this? If got absolutely no Idea how this should work :/

Comment: @BenniHofstätter I agree with harpax, with this full screen layout you will probably have the problem to fit the content on a smaller screen, when you want to scroll a full page with mouse.

Comment: @Stano The Layout will be Responsive when I'm done, so that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @harpax: Thx a lot, I'll test this as soon as possible :)