# JQuery / JS : Detect user's scroll attempt without any window overflow to scroll to

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, overflow

I'm working on a transitioning website, and while I want to use the user's scroll attempt as the transition initiator, I don't want there to be a window scroll bar.

Right now, I'm simply detecting that the user scrolls (I've made my window size 1px taller that the user's screen for a scrollbar, although this is what I'm trying to avoid) with jquery's

```
.scroll(function)
```

method, and using that to transition my page, but **I'd like to detect the user's scroll attempt without having to make my page overflow by a pixel, and thus showing the scrollbar**

How can this be done?

**Messy patch possibility that I know of:**

Positioning the window inside an outer wrapper and hiding the scrollbar in the overflow of the wrapper. This is a patch up job and not a solution. It results in the page content being off-center since not all browsers use the same width for their scrollbars.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154967/jquery-detect-scrolldown). I used it as a reference to make this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sKGx/1/).

[Works only in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMMouseScroll):

```
$('html').on ('DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
    var delta = e.originalEvent.detail;

    if (delta < 0) {
        $('p').text ('You scrolled up');
    } else if (delta > 0) {
        $('p').text ('You scrolled down');
    }

});
```

[Works in Chrome, IE, Opera and Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mousewheel):

```
$('html').on ('mousewheel', function (e) {
    var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;

    if (delta < 0) {
        $('p').text ('You scrolled down');
    } else if (delta > 0) {
        $('p').text ('You scrolled up');
    }
});
```

You'd have to bind it on an element that spans your entire browser screen.

Comment: Testing this out ^_^ brb

Comment: Thoose events are now deprecated and even removed and will not work, use the wheel event that replaces them

Answer (score 12):

The answer from TreeTree can be simplified into one function that supports all browsers. Combine the mousewheel and DOMMouseScroll events since [jQuery supports one or more event parameter(s)](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler). However, my testing showed on() did not work in the latest Firefox. Use bind() instead. You can also combine the var delta declaration to support all browsers:

```
$('html').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
    var delta = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail);

    if (delta < 0) {
        console.log('You scrolled down');
    } else if (delta > 0) {
        console.log('You scrolled up');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

The modern solution relies on the [`wheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) event (IE9+)

```
$('selector').on('wheel', function(event) {
  var delta = {
    x: event.originalEvent.deltaX, 
    y: event.originalEvent.deltaY
  };

  if (delta.x != 0 || delta.y != 0) {
    //user scrolled
  }
});
```

Comment: This has much much much better support than mousewheel and DOMMouseScroll events, even if the "modern" keyword is used in the answer