# How to scroll 100% only the first scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` fulfilling 100% height/width of the browser window. I want my page to scroll 100% height but only the first time scroll. So the site jumps beyond the first `div` and then scrolls like normal. And every time it scrolls the first `div` in sight it should scroll again 100% to the top. I hope I could make my point clear. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for a mouse scroll and preven default just the first time the user does it. Then just do it like normal.

```
 $('#elem').bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
     if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
         scroll_the_first_time(e);
         console.log('Down');
     }
 });

 //IE, Opera, Safari
 $('#elem').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
     if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
         scroll_the_first_time(e);
         console.log('Down');
     }
 });
```

That code doesn belong to me but : 
[Code Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154967/jquery-detect-scrolldown)

Now, this is my code. Using previous i would make my function something like this.

```
var firstTime = true;

function scroll_the_first_time(e){
  if(firsTime){
    e.preventDefault();
    firstTime = !firstTime;
    //do your behavior here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it out now! Will give the feedback afterwards