# Capture event presentation remote with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to capture using `jQuery` the keys pressed from my presentation remote. If I use the remote control in my browser, it emulates a mouse wheel scroll.

*Can someone tell me any way to make it works?*

Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Detect scrolldown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154967/jquery-detect-scrolldown)

Comment: Thanks, of course, I know how to detect the scroll down ;)

Comment: In Prezi presentation you can do it... (to give an example), when you are in the focus of the presentation, you can go forward using the remote presentation... but if you are out, you scroll down...