# jquery works on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I attach the link of my code here. in this, the slider animates correctly when clicking on the corner but I need is that working on the scroll.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.corner').click(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.removeClass("active");
    if ($parent.next().length){
        $parent.next().addClass("active");
    } else {
        $parent.prevAll().last().addClass("active");
    }
});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/freer4/cqqxjjgu/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out this:

```
$('.corner').bind('mousewheel',function() {
    alert(1);
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        $parent.removeClass("active");
        if ($parent.next().length){
            $parent.next().addClass("active");
        } else {
            $parent.prevAll().last().addClass("active");
        }
    });
```

Comment: @user94 -- are you sure?  I pasted this into your fiddle and it worked just fine.

Comment: @user94 Hi, I haven't tested it explicitly but with the experience at my disposal on jquery it "ought" to work.

Comment: @user94-- glad to hear it is working for you-- please don't forget to select dirai's answer. Happy coding!

Comment: if I scroll to top it loads the next slide.but I need the previous slide.is there is anyway @Alexander Nied

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154967/how-to-detect-scroll-direction) looks promising.