# Hide navigation on scroll down

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, scroll, nav

What I need is a navigation menu that hides when user is scrolling down or stops (except in top, then it should be visible), once the user begins to scroll up, the menu should reappear.

So far:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header_nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Punkt1</li>
            <li>Punkt2</li>
            <li>Punkt3</li>
            <li>Punkt4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
* {
    padding:0px; 
    margin:0px;
}
#wrapper {
    height:1200px; 
    width:960px;
    background-color:#567; 
    margin:auto;
}
#header_nav {
    position:fixed; 
    width:960px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#678;
}
```

**JQUERY**:

```
$(function(){
    $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($('body').scrollTop() > 0)
    {
        if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'big')
        {
            $('#header_nav').data('size','small');
            $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                height:'40px'
            },600);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'small')
        {
            $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
            $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
                height:'100px'
            },600);
        }  
    }
});
```

When I scroll nothing happens, my nav just stays the same the entire time. I want it to hide when I scroll down and pause, but once I start to scroll up I want it to fade in.
But I cant seem to get it working, can you guys tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Also made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/iBertel/GGRUL/

Comment: When you say "i cant seem to get it working" what do you mean? Whats the current symptom? Where are you stuck?

Comment: When i scroll nothing happens, my nav just stays the same the entire time... I want it to hide when i scroll down and pause, but once i start to scroll up i want it to fade in.

Comment: Nobody have an idea on how to help me solve this? or maybe its is not possible?

Comment: Your JSFiddle is wrong; you're using MooTools instead of jQuery. (Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GGRUL/13/)

Comment: Well still, nothing happens on my screen when i scroll - does it work on your screen?

Comment: Yep, works fine on mine... I'm using Chrome on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing $('body').scrollTop to $(window).scrollTop seems to get it working:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GGRUL/20/)

Tested in Chrome, Firefox, IE9, Opera on Windows (all latest versions AFAIK).

EDIT:

The following code will fire the resizing mechanism as soon as you start scrolling up:

http://jsfiddle.net/GbXG4/4/

Comment: Yes but i need to scroll all the way to top before it shows again - i need it to show as soon as i start to sroll up... Got any idea on how to fix this? This is the latest: http://jsfiddle.net/iBertel/4uqNL/

Comment: Updated answer with new code, based on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event

Comment: Im so sorry, i didnt formulate it right. I need my menu to hide once i scroll down - and when i scroll up it should become visible again - it should NOT only be visible when i scroll all the way to the top but as soon as i start to scroll up.. You think you can fix this?

Comment: wow - your my hero - thank you very much! One last thing - is it possible to hide it if the window stops aswell unless at top? Like when you scroll down it hides then maybe scroll a bit up and then its visible, then i need to hide again if im not scrolling all the way to top...

Comment: Yep. Abstract the functions out of the window.scroll event, and use setTimeout and clearTimeout: http://jsfiddle.net/37srY/

Comment: Argh - as you test you discover!! One last thing - promise... I need it stay on mouse hover. Like if you scroll up and menu appears, then u take up the mouse and it should not fade away unless you remove the mouse again or scroll down... Is this possible aswell??

Answer (score 0):

Hm, your example works. I've changed Library (left bar) to jQuery and that's all. Also, add `overflow:hidden;` to your `#header_nav`. This will hide text that doesn't fit small height