# How to change URL(hash) when user scroll or click on the link with jquery history plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a single page website. I have many sections in my single page.
I want to change the URL, hash when the user click on the link or scroll up and down.

I want the url to be :

http://mysite.com/**section1**

http://mysite.com/**section2**

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used to try this and I don't know what i did wrong, but it not working well on firefox. Can you give me simple demo page?
thanks.

Comment: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/scroll-link-nav.html Try this as well

Comment: It is not changing the hash. When I try to change the hash , I got scrolling problem on firefox. Can u give me an example to change the hash?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       // downscroll code
       window.location.hash='musection2';
   } else {
      // upscroll code
      window.location.hash='musection1';
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

From [How can I determine the direction of a jQuery scroll event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event)