# How to make the animation work both ways

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code that makes all the div's move to the left side:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#scroll').click(function() {
    $('#scroll').animate({left: '2%'});
    $('.leftslide').animate({left: '-84%'});
    $('.rightslide').animate({left: '9%'});
});
});
```

How to make it work both ways? That the #scroll div moves all the divs to the right after being placed to the left.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4326907/1446146) to get the direction of the scrolling and use this to do either your left animation or right animation