# What code should I write for the reverse $(window).scroll function in jquery for scrolling upwards?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I find the code for window scroll function and appended it to my code, Its working great when I am scrolling down i.e. I have an image that is fading out while scrolling down, but when I scroll back up again, the image is absent because of the previous effect.

so plz help me with this.

HTML part:-

```
<div id="blog">
<img src="trans_blog.png">//i want this image to fade in and out.
</div>
```

jQuery part:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#blog img").fadeIn(2000);
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#blog img").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should do the trick. It will fadeOut element as it goes out of view, and fadeIn as it comes back

```
$(window).scroll( function(){
    $('#blog img').each( function(i){
        var top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();
        var this_bottom = $(this).position().top + $(this).height();
        if(top_of_window > this_bottom){
            $(this).fadeOut();
            } else {
                $(this).fadeIn();
                }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the fadeIn and fadeOut both in the .scroll function and determine the direction of the scroll to do either one or the other.

This post will help you achieve that - [How can I determine the direction of a jQuery scroll event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event)

Answer (score -1):

jQuery Waypoints plugin might be what you need: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/