# To float a div when start scroll down till footer

Tags: jquery

To float a `<div>` when start scroll down and should stop when the `<div>` touches footer and vice versa when scroll up. I'm able to do it by adding this code:

```
if (window_top== div_top){
    $arrow.css({position:'fixed',bottom:0,top:"auto"});
}
```

On [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/be2Ff/9) but my problem is I'm getting shaking effect. How can I stop this shaking effect and do scroll up and down smoothly?

Comment: Seriously, what's the aim of doing that ? look http://jsfiddle.net/be2Ff/14/. Same result without JS and same amount of css

Comment: Hi TCHdvlp, thanks for ur respond, Sorry i did a mistake on the code,check this new code on: http://jsfiddle.net/be2Ff/15/. shaking effect will visible here. I want to stop this shaking effect and do scroll up and down smoothly?

Comment: My am is: i am trying to float a div from a position when scroll 

down(position of this div is fixed) to a certain position(such as, till on 

top of my footer) vertically and want to do vice versa when i did scroll 

up. i google it some how and found this jsfiddle's code and i did some 

modification as per my requirement but the shaking effect kill me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is what you need to do. First of all, The shaking behaviour is totally normal looking to your code, because !!! when you scroll, the test `if (window_top > div_top)` is based on old positions.
Before moving your arrow. when your arrow is under the footer, you set it the way that `window_top == div_top` will be true for the next scroll. Next scroll, `window_top == div_top` will be true, so you move your arrow... etc...   Anyway, what you need to do is :

1 : save initial arrow top position in a global var

```
var initialH = $('#arrow').offset().top;
```

2 : distinct up scroll and down scroll

[How can I determine the direction of a jQuery scroll event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event)

3 : while scrolls are down, just check for

```
if (window_top > div_top)
```

if true, then you can replace `fixed` by `absolute` and attach the arrow to the footer.

4 : if the scroll is up :

if `arrow_top < ( arrow_initial_height + $(window).scrollTop() )`, you musn't do anything, else, set back the original top offset to your arrow, so it will takes back is original position. You will get rid of the shaking effect.

For the smooth scroll, I'm sure there is a ton of tutorials that explain how to do it.

working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/be2Ff/30/

Comment: Hi TCHdvlp, There is no shaking effect anymore..thanks again. i followed all your 4 steps but have doubt on steps 2. pls check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/be2Ff/28/ ......what i want now is when scroll down the arrow should stay at original position when the arrow reaches its original position, not to always stick on yellow footer.....scroll up attached with the arrow when scroll down detached ...like  this..

Comment: My bad. I'll edit my answer. Step 4 must be : if scroll up... So, if scroll up, when `window_top > footer_top` go back to fixed position.

Comment: There are others mistakes, I'll edit the fiddle. look for the fiddle in the answer

Comment: Ok...Hi TCHdvlp, Thanks a llloooooootsssss...This is what i want....and i respect your valuable time that you spent on this to solved my problem...i refer your working fiddle...have a great day