# (Auto)Scroll Up/Down to DivTop

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am new to scripting.

Okay, so I am creating single-paged website (***alturl.com/3ovx5***) having several DIVs with 100% width/height stacked on top of one another.
The fixed buttons on the top animate the page to scroll to the top-of-the-desired-DIV and the button is then highlighted by detecting scrollTop.

---

Now I am trying to put in a **feature similar to http://www.morethanamap.com/developer-stories/** .. This page responds to mouse-scroll and scrolls to the next/previous DIV automatically, something beyond my league.

Using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event) I tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var top0 = $('#page0').position().top;
var top1 = $('#page1').position().top;
// and so on

var oldst = 0; // for OLD-scrollTop

$(document).bind('scroll', function () {
var newst = $(this).scrollTop(); // NEW-scrollTop
 if (newst > oldst) { // user scrolls down
        if (newst < top1) { $('body').animate({scrollTop: top1}, 435); }
   else if (newst > top1 && newst < top2) { $('body').animate({scrollTop: top2}, 435); }
   else if (newst > top2 && newst < top3) { $('body').animate({scrollTop: top3}, 435); }
   else if (newst > top6 && newst < top7) { $('body').animate({scrollTop: top7}, 435); } // and so on
      }
 else { // user scrolls up
        if (newst > top1 && newst < top2) { $('body').animate({scrollTop: top0}, 435); }     
   else if (newst > top2 && newst < top3) { $('body').animate({scrollTop: top1}, 435); }
   else if (newst > top7 || newst = top7) { $('body').animate({scrollTop: top6}, 435); } // and so on
      }
oldst = newst; //update OLD-scrollTop
 });
});
```

The landing-DIV scrolls down okay, but after that the scroll stops working, and instead the page starts jumping up and down. I guessed there  might be a clash in the argument. So, I change the arguments to detect the highlighted (anchor IDed one/two/three....) button, and then scroll up/down accordingly.

New argument becomes:

```
if (newst > oldst) { 
     if (newst < top1) { $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: top1}, 435); }
else if ($('#one').hasClass('selected')) { $('body').animate({scrollTop: top2}, 435); }
else if ($('#two').hasClass('selected')) { $('body').animate({scrollTop: top3}, 435); }
else if ($('#three').hasClass('selected')) { $('body').animate({scrollTop: top4}, 435); } // and so on
    }
```

SAME result. Scroll fails after a single go.

Here is the first demo (***alturl.com/rizw3***) which detects scrollTop.
Here is the second demo (***alturl.com/44wp4***) which detects highlighted buttons.

***HERE is a test (alturl.com/v6sr7)*** that uses alert-messages to show that the arguments (using the code from first demo) are working fine. However, what I wanna do is disable scrollbar once it is accomplished so, it should be either scroll to DIV above, or DIV below (like the google-maps example).

Hope there is a better way, to work this out? :/

Thanks loads!

Comment: Sorry about the non-linked URLs. stackoverflow wont allow me to use more than 2 since I'm new here.

Comment: You might look into [One Page Scroll](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html)

Comment: Thanks Zach!
One-page scroll is great but unfortunately, I can't use it with my site this time because my menu is supposed to scroll up and lock, but with One-page scroll, it cant. Not unless I alter the code a good way. :(

Comment: You only have to comment out the `if(next.length < 1) {` part in [the js](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll/blob/master/jquery.onepage-scroll.js) (line 149)

Comment: Nah, theres a better plugin to use in my case,
Just found it 
http://guidobouman.github.io/jquery-panelsnap/

Thank you Zach :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you are trying to do, somewhat anchoring it to a fixed point on scroll.

Then it's not going to be smooth handling it with `scroll()` function alone because dragging the scrollbar can be a big problem (it's going to be jumpy/jerky), I suggest you do the anchoring with mousewheel event only.

In this solution we are using 'anchored' class as the indicator.

```
$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    var $anchored = $('div.anchored'), 
         delta = e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;   

    if(delta < 0) { 
        //mousewheel down
        $next = $anchored.next();

        if($next.length){
            $('body, html').stop().animate({scrollTop:$next.offset().top},'slow');     
        } 
    }else{ 
        //mousewheel up
        $prev = $anchored.prev();

        if($prev.length){
            $('body, html').stop().animate({scrollTop:$prev.offset().top},'slow');    
        }
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Now if the user scrolls by dragging the scrollbar you also need to move the 'anchored' class indicator to the most visible `<div>` in viewport.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var st = $(this).scrollTop();

$('div').each(function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    if(st >= offset.top && st < offset.top + $(this).outerHeight()){
        $(this).addClass('anchored');
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass('anchored');
    }
});

});
```

See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/t9S5H/5/).

Comment: I've updated the answer to work on cross-browsers. I had fun doing this so I also made one with a navigation :D. Check this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/9bZGd/)

Comment: <3 :D
You rock man. Wish I could understand what is really happening in the script :/

I am having PROBLEMS trying to use it in my site :|
My 'section' are nested inside #page-wrap, called .page
They're all given 100% heights of their parents, including body & html.
Yet, when I try your script my mousewheel just stops scrolling. I recon its the $body = $('body, html') part, which, when removed allows only mousewheel-down to function (not as intended).
In your fiddle, I've tried wrapping your divs in #page-wrap, and naming your divs to '.page' (and changing the code paths), it works fine. :(

Comment: Thank you :D. Actually this solution is preventing the default `mousewheel` scrolling functions, and binding a new anchor scrolling functions. `$('body, html').stop().animate()` is the anchoring method, `$('body')` alone will work on chrome but not on firefox, so for x-browsers we animate both 'body' and 'html'. Can you also create a jsfiddle and add your markup and css so I can help you find the problem.

Comment: Sorry for been gone this long.

Thank you for your 'Excellent' solution (that was composed in minutes) :)
But I found a plugin called Jquery-PanelSnap by Guido Bouman.

Excellent work there too!

Thanks once again Mark :)