# Move an image or element when user scrolls

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to move an image on the scroll event. I used `.animate`, but that moves it all the way, even after the user lets go. I want it to stop when the user stops scrolling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Stack:** Determine the direction of scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event)

By using this, you can then use `.animate`

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MMZ2h/4/)

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$("div").scroll(function (event) {
var st = $(this).scrollTop();
if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    $('img').animate({top: '-=10'}, 10);
} else {
    $('img').animate({top: '+=10'}, 10);
}
lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

***Disregard:*** If you would like the image to move with the page, add `position: fixed;` to the CSS.

Comment: That's pretty obvious. I actually want a small leaf to slowly move up as the user scrolls down. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

> $(window).scroll(function() { $(image).position($(image).position().top + 10); });

depending on your CSS.
If you could provide some code (in a jsFiddle), maybe I would be able to help you a bit better.

Comment: here is the link to the jsfiddle. Can you tell me what's wrong?[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMZ2h/2)