# code works in JSFiddle but not browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jsfiddle

I'm trying to move a fixed div containing an image of an airplane to the right and fade to 0 as the page is scrolled down from the top.

site: http://wp.ccrcc.org

I works fine in JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/G4t4f/77/) but on in the footer of my Wordpress site. I'm obviously missing something here. This may not be the best way to do it anyway since the site is running on bootstrap 3.0.3 with bootstrap.min.js?

```
<style>
    #header-plane {
    z-index: 5;
    width: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 550px;
    top: 200px;}
</style>

<div id="header-plane">
<img src="http://wp.ccrcc.org/wp-content/themes/ccrcc/images/plane-1.png" 
alt="R/C plane" width="400" height="162">
</div>

<div id="footer">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    function flyOut() {
        var top = $(document).scrollTop();
           if (top < 30) {
                 $('#header-plane').animate({
                    'right': '0',
                    'opacity': 0
                 }, 'slow', function() {
                 });        
              }
    }

    $(window).scroll(function () {
      flyOut();
    });
 });
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried not wrapping the JS in the document ready function?  Depending on how WordPress assembles your site, it may not be executing that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like something is breaking `$` by the time your code runs. You could work around that in the short term by using `jQuery` instead of `$`, like this:

```
  jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    function flyOut() {
        var top = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
           if (top < 30) {
                 jQuery('#header-plane').animate({
                    'right': '0',
                    'opacity': 0
                 }, 'slow', function() {
                 });        
              }
    }

    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
      flyOut();
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! One day, I'd like to get the plane to fly back to position from the left when scrolling back to scrollTop() but that's another dream. For now, this works great!

Comment: @user3192829 have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event this can give you an idea how to detect scroll direction.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is how wordpress initialize jQuery. Have a look here: [jQuery noConflict Wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers). In "no-confict" mode, the $ shortcut is not available and the longer jQuery is used. The following construct is a timesaver:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```