# Mouse scroll to next slide

Tags: jquery, jssor

Is there a way to enable mouse scroll (up-down) to control the slides similar to the keys on keyboard?

I am experimenting with [Jssor grid slider](http://www.jssor.com/demos/grid-slider.html) in particular.

Answer (score 3):

First you'll want to [detect the direction of scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event) and perhaps the distance then from this you can navigate the slide show:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       $Next() // next slide
   } else {
      $Prev() // prev slide
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: yes, detect mouse scroll and then call jssor slider api (jssor_slider1.$Next or jssor_slider1.$Prev)

Comment: Thanks for both your answers. However mouse scroll to activate next/prev slide only work when the scroll bar is present, ie after a few scrolls, and when the scroll bar hits the bottom, I can no longer scroll to next slide. Is there a way to overcome this? Btw, my slides scroll vertically and I have tested that the behavior of inability to scroll is consistent on Chrome, IE and Firefox... Thank you

Comment: I reckon you'll be better of using a library, checkout this [plugin](https://github.com/jkat98/scrollToggle).

Comment: That way you can do this: `$('#swipe').bind('swipeup', $Prev);` :)

Comment: You'd detect and handle mousewheel event.