# Error while detecting scroll direction

Tags: javascript, jquery

From this question on - [How can I determine the direction of a jQuery scroll event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event), I wrote this code.

```
var lastS=$(window).scrollTop();

function whatHappened()
{
    var currentS=$(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(lastS,currentS);

    if(currentS>lastS)
    {
       lastS = currentS;
       return "Scroll down";
    }
    else
    {
        lastS = currentS;
        return "Scroll up";
    }
}

$(window).on("mousewheel",function(){
    console.log(whatHappened());
});
```

This seems to work fine but there is a small problem. If I scroll down more than two times and then scroll up it first shows scroll down then scroll up. Similar happens in vice-versa.
What's wrong? 
Please help. Thanks in advance.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3843e/

Answer (score 0):

The mousewheel event is non-standard - in your case, it's probably getting triggered before scroll information is updated, so you're always operating on the "previous" scroll height.

Comment: Okay, but what alternative should I use?

Comment: .scroll(), just like in the example you stated