# How to detect if the user scrolled at the end of the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

using the following will execute action even if the user crolls from the end to the start. I want just when the user scrolls down vertically

```
if( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height() ) {

     //do stuff
}
```

this is my code so far,

```
   function addEvent( obj, type, fn ) {


     if ( obj.attachEvent ) {
        obj['e'+type+fn] = fn;
       obj[type+fn] = function(){obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event );}
       obj.attachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] );
    } else
      obj.addEventListener( type, fn, false );

   }
  addEvent(window, 'scroll', function(event) {

    if( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height() )  {
    load();
    }

});
```

Comment: Works for me in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pcbxmqzu/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onscroll = function(e) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        // do stuff
    }
};
```

Comment: this doesn't work on IE unfortunately

Comment: Yeah, good call, I had just come to that same conclusion. I originally tried it in Chrome.

Comment: window.onscroll = function(e) {
        if ((window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
            alert("bottom");
        }
    };

Comment: Basically replace window.ScrollY with document.documentElement.scrollTop and you should be good.

Comment: Tested in Firefox, Chrome, and IE this time ;)

Comment: that doesn't work not even with chrome

Comment: It worked for me. I'll go try to break it.

Comment: I updated Chrome and then I had to use this: window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop. My Firefox and IE are current and this fixed the Chrome compatibility with the new version.

Comment: Seems like there should be a more standard way, but I suppose that's the nature of the beast with web design.

Comment: Let me know if that's working for you too.

Comment: @ David Lounsbrough : yes your last solution works ! but then , when working on an application that should be delivered to a client; we really should not tell them that browser must be updated to make it work. which make me wonder if this works on not updated browsers or not

Comment: Yeah, I only tested this one in the most updated browsers, hard to say how far back you'd have to go to break it. Good luck with your testing.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
   }
});
```

or this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()) {
           alert("bottom!");
       }
    });
```

See [**How to detect user reached bottom of page while scrolling**](http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-detect-user-reached-bottom-of.html)

Also you may be interested in [**Infinite Scroll Paging using Jquery and Ajax**](http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2013/12/infinite-scroll-paging-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html)

Comment: I tried this, but some how my action is executed whether I scroll down or up

Comment: well , that was my initial try...s mentionned in the post

Comment: @N.G see the second link i posted in the edit, i implemented it in my application and it works fine

Comment: I'm also confused, it should have worked properly but it works fine with IE but on firefox and chrome it works when I scroll up and not down, I may be making something wrong, please see edit for the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()) {
        //your stuffs here
    }
});
```