# How to use scroll instead of mousewheel Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to convert the fallowing working script as so it works on scroll regardless of how the site is being scrolled.

```
    // // HEADER 
    $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() <= 20 || event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 && $(document).scrollTop() <= 105) {
            //console.log('large');
            headerLarge();
        }
        else if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 && $(document).scrollTop() <= 120) {
            //console.log('medium');
            headerMed();
        } 
        else if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 && $(document).scrollTop() >= 100) {
            //console.log('small');
            headerSm();
        }
    });
```

I tried using the following without success:

$(document).on('scroll', function(event) { ...

Comment: So in fact you want to detect scrolling way, up or down???

Comment: I need to call a specific js function (where I'm changing css) depending on scrolling of the page at different stages.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

});
```

Comment: Well but I still have event.originalEvent.wheelDelta on if statements, any suggestions on how to get same functionality using scroll?

Comment: humm. i don't think scroll event comes with this data. what you're trying to accomplish? if you're trying to detect the scroll orientation, there's a solution for that on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using **$(window).scroll()** like this:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {   

       alert("scrolling!");

});
```

Taken From [**Infinite Scroll Paging**](http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-detect-user-reached-bottom-of.html)