# Jquery time up timer , i have a code for timer but it start while page load

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="">  
  <p class=" count1 Count">240</p>
</div>

<div class=" count-item">  
  <p class=" Count">410</p>
</div>

<div class="">  
  <p class="count3 Count" >6</p>
</div>

<div class="">  
  <p class=" count4 Count">4</p>
</div>

<script>
  $('.Count').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $({ Counter: 0 }).animate({ Counter: $this.text() }, {
      duration: 1500,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function () {
        $this.text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
      }
   });
});
</script>
```

Here is a function for timer but I want to put offset('90%'). 
So how can I Use offset with this function. can anyone help me. I am tired to make it with offset.

I have a code for timer but it start while page load.
 I want to load it when scroll page it's own position, I meant with offset

Answer (score 0):

[Edited]
Check this answer. You can detect scroll directions and trigger any event at a certain position of the scroll.

[How can I determine the direction of a jQuery scroll event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event)

Comment: here is no problem with
$(document).ready(
--------
 );
i want to start timer while page scroll its own position

Comment: No one have any answer for this . ??
:(

Comment: @NavtoshAdhikari I edited my answer, please check it out

Comment: okay that's great. It working but having troubling with other other devices positions